# Create tap-able "links" in the NSAttributedString of a UILabel?

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uilabel, nsattributedstring, uitapgesturerecognizer

Many applications have text and in this text are web hyperlinks in rounded rect. When I click them `UIWebView` opens. What puzzles me is that they often have custom links, for example if words starts with # it is also clickable and the application responds by opening another view. How can I do that? Is it possible with `UILabel` or do I need `UITextView` or something else?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505334/how-can-i-accurately-detect-if-a-link-is-clicked-inside-uilabels-in-swift-4/50626108#50626108 for a fully working `Swift 4` solution. It uses `UITextView` but makes it behave like a `UILabel`. I tried the solutions on here, and failed to get accurate link detection.

Comment: See https://medium.com/swlh/clickable-link-on-a-swift-label-or-textview-98bbb067451d

Comment: Just use `UITextView`, it has delegate `shouldInteractWith` that you can customize how the action should be.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

In general, if we want to have a clickable link in text displayed by UILabel, we would need to resolve two independent tasks:

1. Changing the appearance of a portion of the text to look like a link
2. Detecting and handling touches on the link (opening an URL is a particular case)

The first one is easy. Starting from iOS 6 UILabel supports display of attributed strings. All you need to do is to create and configure an instance of NSMutableAttributedString:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"String with a link" attributes:nil];
NSRange linkRange = NSMakeRange(14, 4); // for the word "link" in the string above

NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.05 green:0.4 blue:0.65 alpha:1.0],
                                  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) };
[attributedString setAttributes:linkAttributes range:linkRange];

// Assign attributedText to UILabel
label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

That's it! The code above makes UILabel to display **String with a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519273/2923345)**

Now we should detect touches on this link. The idea is to catch all taps within UILabel and figure out whether the location of the tap was close enough to the link. To catch touches we can add tap gesture recognizer to the label. Make sure to enable userInteraction for the label, it's turned off by default:

```
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[label addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnLabel:)]];
```

Now the most sophisticated stuff: finding out whether the tap was on where the link is displayed and not on any other portion of the label. If we had single-lined UILabel, this task could be solved relatively easy by hardcoding the area bounds where the link is displayed, but let's solve this problem more elegantly and for general case - multiline UILabel without preliminary knowledge about the link layout.

One of the approaches is to use capabilities of Text Kit API introduced in iOS 7:

```
// Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeZero];
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];

// Configure layoutManager and textStorage
[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

// Configure textContainer
textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode;
textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines;
```

Save created and configured instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage in properties in your class (most likely UIViewController's descendant) - we'll need them in other methods.

Now, each time the label changes its frame, update textContainer's size:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.textContainer.size = self.label.bounds.size;
}
```

And finally, detect whether the tap was exactly on the link:

```
- (void)handleTapOnLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInLabel = [tapGesture locationInView:tapGesture.view];
    CGSize labelSize = tapGesture.view.bounds.size;
    CGRect textBoundingBox = [self.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:self.textContainer];
    CGPoint textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                              (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                         locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
    NSInteger indexOfCharacter = [self.layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:locationOfTouchInTextContainer
                                                            inTextContainer:self.textContainer
                                   fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];
    NSRange linkRange = NSMakeRange(14, 4); // it's better to save the range somewhere when it was originally used for marking link in attributed string
    if (NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, linkRange)) {
        // Open an URL, or handle the tap on the link in any other way
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stackoverflow.com/"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I organize this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? I'm creating and configuring instances within `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and hosting the `handleTapOnLabel` function in it too. But at `cell.textLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: cell, action: "handleTapOnLabel:"))`, I'm getting `unrecognized selector`.

Comment: This solution assumes that the label's `textAlignment` attribute is set to `NSTextAlignmentCenter`. If you are using non-centered text, you'll need to adjust the calculation of your `textContainerOffset` in the above code.

Comment: @BradB i need to do that i have left-alligned 3-line UILabel. How to adjust `textContainerOffset`?

Comment: @AndreyM. When calculating the `x` value of `textContainerOffset`, the constant `0.5` is used. This will calculate the correct position for `NSTextAlignmentCent‌er`. To align left, natural or justified, use a value of `0.0`. To align right, use `1.0`.

Comment: Works great!, But it is not working for mixed language in my case. Try using english + thai. I am getting wrong character index in NSLocationInRange. Example - "Ada Apa Dengan Cinta 2 bercerita tentang kisah cinta Rangga (Nicholas Saputra) dan Cinta (Dian Sastrowardoyo) empat belas tahun kemudian set  ดูเพิ่มเติม".  Label - "<UILabel: 0x7c73b290; frame = (22 160; 440 30); text = 'Ada Apa Dengan Cinta 2 be...'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c032a40>; layer = <_UILabelLayer:>>" Try it and if found any solution share that with me.

Comment: For me, `indexOfCharacter` is always returning `0` and `textBoundingBox.size` is always `0, 0`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: For some reason, `self.textContainer.size = self.myLabel.bounds.size;` is not updating the `textContainer.size`. It's continuing to return zero, even though my label's bounds size is not zero.

Comment: Will this work for text with new line character also?

Comment: It work for me also, but only for single line of label. If Label contain more than 1 line then this method is not working proper.  Can anyone tell he to perform same task with multiple line

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper Add the self.textContainer.size = self.label.bounds.size; in the handleTapOnLabel . That worked for me

Comment: For me the problem is that it does not correctly get the index for the symbol. I have checked and it appears to be the following: sometimes the neighbour characters can have difference in their indexes 2. As I understand it might be because the width for all the characters is considered to be equal, even though some characters are obviously wider (like 'm' for example is much wider that 'i'). Is there any solution for that?

Comment: This logic is inconsistent and does not work for different phone sizes. May I suggest this working alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962530/hyperlinks-in-a-uitextview

Comment: Two key points I would add to the existing solution: 1. Ensure the attributed text contains the text alignment attribute. Add it with the attribute `NSParagraphStyleAttributeName` and the text alignment property of your label. 2. Ensure the `NSTextStorage` has the font attribute set using `NSFontAttributeName` and the font property of your label.

Comment: For unrecognized selector in uitableviewcell , I just fix it by changing the variable name layoutManager to layoutmanager as layoutManager is already a property of uitableviewcell.I change the variable name to prevent eh confusion

Comment: @Andrew, you must retain the textStorage object, so that you can avoid the related objects release and get the correct indexOfCharacter.

Comment: I find it easier to create a button and simply changes it's attributedText programatically if the tap recognition will be for the whole text/label

Answer (score 86):

I am extending [@NAlexN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519273/242682) original detailed solution, with [@zekel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29352519/242682) excellent extension of `UITapGestureRecognizer`, and providing in **Swift**.

### Extending UITapGestureRecognizer

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(
            x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
            y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y
        )
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(
            x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
            y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y
        )
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }

}
```

### Usage

Setup `UIGestureRecognizer` to send actions to `tapLabel:`, and you can detect if the target ranges is being tapped on in `myLabel`.

```
@IBAction func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(myLabel, inRange: targetRange1) {
        print("Tapped targetRange1")
    } else if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(myLabel, inRange: targetRange2) {
        print("Tapped targetRange2")
    } else {
        print("Tapped none")
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: The `UILabel` line break mode must be set to wrap by word/char. Somehow, `NSTextContainer` will assume that the text is single line only if the line break mode is otherwise.

Comment: @rodrigo-ruiz I added an example for multi-line below

Comment: @Koen It does work with multiple links. See the usage for the example with `targetRange1` and `targetRange2`.

Comment: For anyone still having issues with multiple lines or incorrect range issues, set your UILabel to _Attributed_, then allow _word wrap_, and set the attributed text of the label to `NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: text)` where 'text' is an `NSAttributedString`

Comment: @Mofe-hendyEjegi i'm still having issues with multi line text. I'm using auto layout with constraints on the uilabel width. Would that matter?

Comment: I had to manually set textContainerOffset.x to 0, as the computed value was not working for textAlignment left. Is it working for you guys? I think the computed value is right if the alignment was centre.

Comment: does not work for center aligned uilabels also. The whole idea of guessing the textlayout used to that uilabel in queistion seems highly misguided. It's bound to break somewhere.

Comment: @keno make sure user interaction is enabled

Comment: Anyone has a strong solution for this issue with multiline labels? I'm finding that I can only get the right index of a character tapped in the first line

Comment: How to solve it for RTL text? In my case, I have to localize text.

Comment: Finally, Its worked for me! Thanks mat.

Comment: for me it helped to add font and paragraphStyle in code instead of xib

        let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraph.alignment = .justified
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraph,
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.regular(size: 13)
        ]
        attriString.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attriString.length))

Answer (score 71):

Old question but if anyone can use a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel`, then it is easy. Standard URLs, phone numbers etc will be automatically detected (and be clickable).

However, if you need custom detection, that is, if you want to be able to call any custom method after a user clicks on a particular word, you need to use `NSAttributedStrings` with an `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute that will point to a custom URL scheme(as opposed to having the http url scheme by default). [Ray Wenderlich has it covered here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#textViewLinks)

Quoting the code from the aforementioned link:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is an example by @marcelofabri_"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                     value:@"username://marcelofabri_"
                     range:[[attributedString string] rangeOfString:@"@marcelofabri_"]];

NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor],
                             NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                             NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlinePatternSolid)};

// assume that textView is a UITextView previously created (either by code or Interface Builder)
textView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes; // customizes the appearance of links
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
textView.delegate = self;
```

To detect those link clicks, implement this:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {
    if ([[URL scheme] isEqualToString:@"username"]) {
        NSString *username = [URL host]; 
        // do something with this username
        // ...
        return NO;
    }
    return YES; // let the system open this URL
}
```

PS: Make sure your `UITextView` is `selectable`.

Comment: This should be accepted. I spent quite a lot of time trying to get code by @NAlexN working and then implemented it with UITextView in 5 minutes.

Comment: The problem with this is if you want to make it generic for different links you have to check what is the URL to take appropriate action

Comment: `Make sure your UITextView is selectable` : this saved my day

Comment: I've added simple UITextView subclass implementing this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/65980444/286361

Answer (score 34):

(My answer builds on @NAlexN's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519273/168594). I won't duplicate his detailed explanation of each step here.)

**I found it most convenient and straightforward to add support for tap-able UILabel text as a category to UITapGestureRecognizer.** (You don't *have* to use UITextView's data detectors, as some answers suggest.)

Add the following method to your UITapGestureRecognizer category:

```
/**
 Returns YES if the tap gesture was within the specified range of the attributed text of the label.
 */
- (BOOL)didTapAttributedTextInLabel:(UILabel *)label inRange:(NSRange)targetRange {
    NSParameterAssert(label != nil);

    CGSize labelSize = label.bounds.size;
    // create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeZero];
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];

    // configure layoutManager and textStorage
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    // configure textContainer for the label
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode;
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines;
    textContainer.size = labelSize;

    // find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInLabel = [self locationInView:label];
    CGRect textBoundingBox = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
    CGPoint textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                              (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                         locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
    NSInteger indexOfCharacter = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:locationOfTouchInTextContainer
                                                            inTextContainer:textContainer
                                   fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];
    if (NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

#### Example Code

```
// (in your view controller)    
// create your label, gesture recognizer, attributed text, and get the range of the "link" in your label
myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[myLabel addGestureRecognizer:
   [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                           action:@selector(handleTapOnLabel:)]]; 

// create your attributed text and keep an ivar of your "link" text range
NSAttributedString *plainText;
NSAttributedString *linkText;
plainText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Add label links with UITapGestureRecognizer"
                                                   attributes:nil];
linkText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" Learn more..."
                                                  attributes:@{
                                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]
                                                  }];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[attrText appendAttributedString:plainText];
[attrText appendAttributedString:linkText];

// ivar -- keep track of the target range so you can compare in the callback
targetRange = NSMakeRange(plainText.length, linkText.length);
```

#### Gesture Callback

```
// handle the gesture recognizer callback and call the category method
- (void)handleTapOnLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    BOOL didTapLink = [tapGesture didTapAttributedTextInLabel:myLabel
                                            inRange:targetRange];
    NSLog(@"didTapLink: %d", didTapLink);

}
```

Comment: just about got this working - but i'm having trouble with linkText.location - my NSAttributedString doesn't have this property?

Comment: @MattBolt Oops, that was a mistake. That should be the start index of the link text, in this example it should be `plainText.length`.

Comment: Error occurred in  CGPoint locationOfTouchInLabel = [self locationInView:label];

Comment: @zekel Thank you very mich for this solution. But could you explain what exactly you mean by "Add the following method to your UITapGestureRecognizer category"? Not sure what I should do here.

Comment: @eivindml You can use categories to add methods to existing classes, which is useful for working with classes you didn't write, such as `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Here is [some info](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) on adding categories.

Comment: @zekel Ok, thank you :) So it's the same as `extensions` in Swift. Im implementing this using Swift now and have no prior experience with ObjC, so wasn't sure what this as about.

Comment: When I add blank spaces at the start of label like "<8 spaces>I accept Terms". I have to tap on terms, but the tap only gets detected near the letter m or s

Comment: We started using this convenient solution, but it was not accurate enough when using multiple font style attributes in the original `UILabel`. We have solved this by applying the original string attributes from `UILabel` to `NSTextStorage`, so `NSLayoutManager` can render the exact location of the target text range. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67618676/2439941 for the code snippet.

Answer (score 32):

The UIButtonTypeCustom is a clickable label if you don't set any images for it.

Comment: Only if the whole text is clickable and only one link.

Answer (score 27):

Translating @samwize's Extension to Swift 4:

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {
    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        guard let attrString = label.attributedText else {
            return false
        }

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: .zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attrString)

        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }
}
```

To set up the recognizer (once you colored the text and stuff):

```
lblTermsOfUse.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
lblTermsOfUse.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapOnLabel(_:))))
```

...then the gesture recognizer:

```
@objc func handleTapOnLabel(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let text = lblAgreeToTerms.attributedText?.string else {
        return
    }

    if let range = text.range(of: NSLocalizedString("_onboarding_terms", comment: "terms")),
        recognizer.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: lblAgreeToTerms, inRange: NSRange(range, in: text)) {
        goToTermsAndConditions()
    } else if let range = text.range(of: NSLocalizedString("_onboarding_privacy", comment: "privacy")),
        recognizer.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: lblAgreeToTerms, inRange: NSRange(range, in: text)) {
        goToPrivacyPolicy()
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. `didTapAttributedTextInLabel` needs an `NSRange` as an argument but `rangeTerms` returns something different. Also the `handleTapOnLabel` function should be marked with `@objc` in Swift 4.

Answer (score 24):

`UITextView` supports data-detectors in OS3.0, whereas `UILabel` doesn't.

If you enable the data-detectors on the `UITextView` and your text contains URLs, phone numbers, etc. they will appear as links.

Comment: yeah, I know about this, but I need also custom detection, e.g. #some_word as mentioned in my question

Comment: @Lope You can still do that, just assign them a custom url-scheme like `hashtag://` or something, then use [`textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview) to detect it. See the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34014655/1161906

Answer (score 23):

Most simple and reliable approach is to use UITextView as [Kedar Paranjape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34014655/286361) recommended.  Based on [answer of Karl Nosworthy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28572505/286361) I finally came up with a simple UITextView subclass:

```
class LinkTextView: UITextView, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    typealias Links = [String: String]
    
    typealias OnLinkTap = (URL) -> Bool
    
    var onLinkTap: OnLinkTap?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        isEditable = false
        isSelectable = true
        isScrollEnabled = false //to have own size and behave like a label
        delegate = self
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    func addLinks(_ links: Links) {
        guard attributedText.length > 0  else {
            return
        }
        let mText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
        
        for (linkText, urlString) in links {
            if linkText.count > 0 {
                let linkRange = mText.mutableString.range(of: linkText)
                mText.addAttribute(.link, value: urlString, range: linkRange)
            }
        }
        attributedText = mText
    }
    
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        return onLinkTap?(URL) ?? true
    }
    
    // to disable text selection
    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.selectedTextRange = nil
    }
}
```

Usage is very simple:

```
    let linkTextView = LinkTextView()
    let tu = "Terms of Use"
    let pp = "Privacy Policy"
    linkTextView.text = "Please read the Some Company \(tu) and \(pp)"
    linkTextView.addLinks([
        tu: "https://some.com/tu",
        pp: "https://some.com/pp"
    ])
    linkTextView.onLinkTap = { url in
        print("url: \(url)")
        return true
    }
```

[image]

Note that `isScrollEnabled` is false by default, as in most cases we need small label-like view with own size and without scrolling. Just set it to true if you want a scrollable text view.

Also note that the UITextView unlike UILabel has default text padding. To remove it and make layout same as in UILabel just add:

```
linkTextView.textContainerInset = .zero
linkTextView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

Implementing `onLinkTap` closure is not necessary, without it URLs are automatically open by UIApplication.

Links appearance can be customized by setting `linkTextAttributes` property of the UITextView.

As Text selection is undesirable in most cases, but it can't be turned off it is dismissed in delegate method ([Thanks to Carson Vo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64089889/286361))

Comment: This is nicely done, tested and it works well. Thanks 

Comment: Cool man, thanks!

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but `linkTextView.onLinkTap` seems never to be hit. I prefer using a segue behind the code, so it's important to catch that. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: Solved it. I had to pull out the UITextViewDelegate implementation from the subclass and put it into the UIViewController. Now it works.

Answer (score 22):

Some answers didn't work for me as expected. This is Swift solution that supports also `textAlignment` and multiline. No subclassing needed, just this `UITapGestureRecognizer` extension:

```
import UIKit


extension UITapGestureRecognizer {
    
    func didTapAttributedString(_ string: String, in label: UILabel) -> Bool {
        
        guard let text = label.text else {
            
            return false
        }
        
        let range = (text as NSString).range(of: string)
        return self.didTapAttributedText(label: label, inRange: range)
    }
    
    private func didTapAttributedText(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        
        guard let attributedText = label.attributedText else {
            
            assertionFailure("attributedText must be set")
            return false
        }
        
        let textContainer = createTextContainer(for: label)
        
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
        if let font = label.font {
            
            textStorage.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
        }
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let alignmentOffset = aligmentOffset(for: label)
        
        let xOffset = ((label.bounds.size.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * alignmentOffset) - textBoundingBox.origin.x
        let yOffset = ((label.bounds.size.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * alignmentOffset) - textBoundingBox.origin.y
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - xOffset, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - yOffset)
        
        let characterTapped = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        
        let lineTapped = Int(ceil(locationOfTouchInLabel.y / label.font.lineHeight)) - 1
        let rightMostPointInLineTapped = CGPoint(x: label.bounds.size.width, y: label.font.lineHeight * CGFloat(lineTapped))
        let charsInLineTapped = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: rightMostPointInLineTapped, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        
        return characterTapped < charsInLineTapped ? targetRange.contains(characterTapped) : false
    }
    
    private func createTextContainer(for label: UILabel) -> NSTextContainer {
        
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: label.bounds.size)
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        return textContainer
    }
    
    private func aligmentOffset(for label: UILabel) -> CGFloat {
        
        switch label.textAlignment {
            
        case .left, .natural, .justified:
            
            return 0.0
        case .center:
            
            return 0.5
        case .right:
            
            return 1.0
            
            @unknown default:
            
            return 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var label : UILabel!
    
    let selectableString1 = "consectetur"
    let selectableString2 = "cupidatat"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \(selectableString1) adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat \(selectableString2) non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
        label.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(string: text))
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelTapped))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    @objc func labelTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        if gesture.didTapAttributedString(selectableString1, in: label) {
            
            print("\(selectableString1) tapped")
        } else if gesture.didTapAttributedString(selectableString2, in: label) {
            
            print("\(selectableString2) tapped")
        } else {
            
            print("Text tapped")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great add, this must have been on the TOP!

Comment: Nice answer. Just a small typo: aligmentOffset ->  _alignmentOffset_ :)

Comment: worked well than other solutions provided here, thanks mate.

Comment: I tried almost all of the other answers but this is the only one that works properly and is not hacky. Well done.

Comment: Worked for swift 5 also. Awesome, Thank you.

Comment: yes you are right, all other solutions are not working properly ... you are champ !!!

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

As I mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827035/tap-gesture-on-part-of-uilabel/32746148#32746148), 
here is a light-weighted library I created specially for links in UILabel [FRHyperLabel](https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel).

To achieve an effect like this:

*[Lorem](http://www.google.com) ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. [Pellentesque](http://www.google.com) quis [blandit](http://www.google.com) eros, sit amet vehicula justo. Nam at urna neque. [Maecenas](http://www.google.com) ac sem eu sem porta dictum nec vel tellus.*

use code:

```cs
//Step 1: Define a normal attributed string for non-link texts
NSString *string = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis blandit eros, sit amet vehicula justo. Nam at urna neque. Maecenas ac sem eu sem porta dictum nec vel tellus.";
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]};

label.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:string attributes:attributes];


//Step 2: Define a selection handler block
void(^handler)(FRHyperLabel *label, NSString *substring) = ^(FRHyperLabel *label, NSString *substring){
    NSLog(@"Selected: %@", substring);
};


//Step 3: Add link substrings
[label setLinksForSubstrings:@[@"Lorem", @"Pellentesque", @"blandit", @"Maecenas"] withLinkHandler:handler];
```

Comment: what if label text is dynamic coming from API and you don`t know the text length then how to make a link .

Comment: Works fine on Swift 4 as well.

Comment: Do you still update FRHyperLabel? I can't get the hyperlinks to work if my attributed string contains ruby text created with kCTRubyAnnotationAttributeName

Answer (score 8):

**Here is a swift version of NAlexN's answer.**

```
class TapabbleLabel: UILabel {

let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
var textStorage = NSTextStorage() {
    didSet {
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    }
}

var onCharacterTapped: ((label: UILabel, characterIndex: Int) -> Void)?

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
    didSet {
        if let attributedText = attributedText {
            textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
        } else {
            textStorage = NSTextStorage()
        }
    }
}

override var lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode {
    didSet {
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
    }
}

override var numberOfLines: Int {
    didSet {
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
    }
}

/**
 Creates a new view with the passed coder.

 :param: aDecoder The a decoder

 :returns: the created new view.
 */
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setUp()
}

/**
 Creates a new view with the passed frame.

 :param: frame The frame

 :returns: the created new view.
 */
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUp()
}

/**
 Sets up the view.
 */
func setUp() {
    userInteractionEnabled = true
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
    tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TapabbleLabel.labelTapped(_:)))
    addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textContainer.size = bounds.size
}

func labelTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard gesture.state == .Ended else {
        return
    }

    let locationOfTouch = gesture.locationInView(gesture.view)
    let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(textContainer)
    let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (bounds.width - textBoundingBox.width) / 2 - textBoundingBox.minX,
                                      y: (bounds.height - textBoundingBox.height) / 2 - textBoundingBox.minY)        
    let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouch.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                 y: locationOfTouch.y - textContainerOffset.y)
    let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(locationOfTouchInTextContainer,
                                                                inTextContainer: textContainer,
                                                                fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    onCharacterTapped?(label: self, characterIndex: indexOfCharacter)
}
}
```

You can then create an instance of that class inside your `viewDidLoad` method like this:

```
let label = TapabbleLabel()
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(label)
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[view]-|",
                                               options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view" : label]))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[view]-|",
                                               options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["view" : label]))

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "String with a link", attributes: nil)
let linkRange = NSMakeRange(14, 4); // for the word "link" in the string above

let linkAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor(), NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue,
    NSLinkAttributeName: "http://www.apple.com"]
attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range:linkRange)

label.attributedText = attributedString

label.onCharacterTapped = { label, characterIndex in
    if let attribute = label.attributedText?.attribute(NSLinkAttributeName, atIndex: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? String,
        let url = NSURL(string: attribute) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

It's better to have a custom attribute to use when a character is tapped. Now, it's the `NSLinkAttributeName`, but could be anything and you can use that value to do other things other than opening a url, you can do any custom action.

Comment: This is great! I replaced the TapGestureRecognizer with a LongPressRecognizer and it breaks tableview scrolling. Any suggestion for how to prevent the gestureRecognizer from breaking tableview scrolling? Thanks!!!

Comment: You may use shouldRecognizeSimultaneously https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer

Answer (score 8):

Worked in Swift 3, pasting the entire code here

```
    //****Make sure the textview 'Selectable' = checked, and 'Editable = Unchecked'

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var theNewTextView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //****textview = Selectable = checked, and Editable = Unchecked

        theNewTextView.delegate = self

        let theString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Agree to Terms")
        let theRange = theString.mutableString.range(of: "Terms")

        theString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "ContactUs://", range: theRange)

        let theAttribute = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue] as [String : Any]

        theNewTextView.linkTextAttributes = theAttribute

     theNewTextView.attributedText = theString             

theString.setAttributes(theAttribute, range: theRange)

    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

        if (URL.scheme?.hasPrefix("ContactUs://"))! {

            return false //interaction not allowed
        }

        //*** Set storyboard id same as VC name
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController((self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TheLastViewController"))! as UIViewController, animated: true)

        return true
    }

}
```

Comment: This is new API, just allow from Swift 10 and above :(

Comment: @t4nhpt You mean iOS 10 ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I created UILabel subclass named [ResponsiveLabel](https://github.com/hsusmita/ResponsiveLabel) which is based on textkit API introduced in iOS 7. It uses the same approach suggested by [NAlexN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2923345/nalexn). It provides flexibility to specify a pattern to search in the text. One can specify styles to be applied to those patterns as well as action to be performed on tapping the patterns.

```
//Detects email in text

 NSString *emailRegexString = @"[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}";
 NSError *error;
 NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc]initWithPattern:emailRegexString options:0 error:&error];
 PatternDescriptor *descriptor = [[PatternDescriptor alloc]initWithRegex:regex withSearchType:PatternSearchTypeAll withPatternAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}];
 [self.customLabel enablePatternDetection:descriptor];
```

If you want to make a string clickable, you can do this way. This code applies attributes to each occurrence of the string "text".

```
PatternTapResponder tapResponder = ^(NSString *string) {
    NSLog(@"tapped = %@",string);
};

[self.customLabel enableStringDetection:@"text" withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor],
                                                                 RLTapResponderAttributeName: tapResponder}];
```

Comment: ResponsiveLabel seems good components to work with, but by some reason I can't set color for clickable text, and can't set array of clickable strings.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander Right now, ResponsiveLabel does not have method which takes an array of string and makes them clickable. You can create an issue on github and I will implement this soon.

Comment: Yea it's not an issue, but good to have this method that takes array.

Answer (score 6):

Here is example code to hyperlink UILabel:
Source:http://sickprogrammersarea.blogspot.in/2014/03/adding-links-to-uilabel.html

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TTTAttributedLabel.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    UITextField *loc;
    TTTAttributedLabel *data;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 80, 25) ];
    [lbl setText:@"Text:"];
    [lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16]];
    [lbl setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    loc=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 20, 300, 30)];
    //loc.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    loc.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    loc.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    //[loc setText:@"Enter Location"];
    loc.clearsOnInsertion = YES;
    loc.leftView=lbl;
    loc.leftViewMode=UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [loc setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:loc];
    [loc setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(110, 70, 70,30);
    UIButton *srchButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    srchButton.frame=frameimg;
    [srchButton setTitle:@"Go" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [srchButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    srchButton.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [srchButton addTarget:self action:@selector(go:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self.view addSubview:srchButton];
    data = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 120,self.view.frame.size.width,200) ];
    [data setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:16]];
    [data setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    data.numberOfLines=0;
    data.delegate = self;
    data.enabledTextCheckingTypes=NSTextCheckingTypeLink|NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber;
    [self.view addSubview:data];
}
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSString *val=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    if ([[url scheme] hasPrefix:@"mailto"]) {
              NSLog(@" mail URL Selected : %@",url);
        MFMailComposeViewController *comp=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        [comp setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            NSString *recp=[[val substringToIndex:[val length]] substringFromIndex:7];
            NSLog(@"Recept : %@",recp);
            [comp setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:recp, nil]];
            [comp setSubject:@"From my app"];
            [comp setMessageBody:@"Hello bro" isHTML:NO];
            [comp setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
            [self presentViewController:comp animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
    else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:val]];
    }
}
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    if(error)
    {
        UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Erorr" message:@"Some error occureed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alrt show];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber
{
    NSLog(@"Phone Number Selected : %@",phoneNumber);
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumber]]];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *Notpermitted=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Your device doesn't support this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [Notpermitted show];
    }
}
-(void)go:(id)sender
{
    [data setText:loc.text];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Reached");
    [loc resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like there is reported in earlier answer the UITextView is able to handle touches on links. This can easily be extended by making other parts of the text work as links. The AttributedTextView library is a UITextView subclass that makes it very easy to handle these. For more info see: https://github.com/evermeer/AttributedTextView

You can make any part of the text interact like this (where textView1 is a UITextView IBOutlet):

```
textView1.attributer =
    "1. ".red
    .append("This is the first test. ").green
    .append("Click on ").black
    .append("evict.nl").makeInteract { _ in
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://evict.nl")!, options: [:], completionHandler: { completed in })
    }.underline
    .append(" for testing links. ").black
    .append("Next test").underline.makeInteract { _ in
        print("NEXT")
    }
    .all.font(UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 16))
    .setLinkColor(UIColor.purple)
```

And for handling hashtags and mentions you can use code like this:

```
textView1.attributer = "@test: What #hashtags do we have in @evermeer #AtributedTextView library"
    .matchHashtags.underline
    .matchMentions
    .makeInteract { link in
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://twitter.com\(link.replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: ""))")!, options: [:], completionHandler: { completed in })
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a Swift implementation that is about as minimal as possible that also includes touch feedback. Caveats:

1. You must set fonts in your NSAttributedStrings
2. You can only use NSAttributedStrings!
3. You must ensure your links cannot wrap (use non breaking spaces: `"\u{a0}"`)
4. You cannot change the lineBreakMode or numberOfLines after setting the text
5. You create links by adding attributes with `.link` keys

.

```
public class LinkLabel: UILabel {
    private var storage: NSTextStorage?
    private let textContainer = NSTextContainer()
    private let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    private var selectedBackgroundView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textContainer.layoutManager = layoutManager
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        selectedBackgroundView.isHidden = true
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3333)
        selectedBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        addSubview(selectedBackgroundView)
    }

    public required convenience init(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        textContainer.size = frame.size
    }

    public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        setLink(for: touches)
    }

    public override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        setLink(for: touches)
    }

    private func setLink(for touches: Set<UITouch>) {
        if let pt = touches.first?.location(in: self), let (characterRange, _) = link(at: pt) {
            let glyphRange = layoutManager.glyphRange(forCharacterRange: characterRange, actualCharacterRange: nil)
            selectedBackgroundView.frame = layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, in: textContainer).insetBy(dx: -3, dy: -3)
            selectedBackgroundView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            selectedBackgroundView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    public override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
        selectedBackgroundView.isHidden = true
    }

    public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        selectedBackgroundView.isHidden = true

        if let pt = touches.first?.location(in: self), let (_, url) = link(at: pt) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }

    private func link(at point: CGPoint) -> (NSRange, URL)? {
        let touchedGlyph = layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: point, in: textContainer)
        let touchedChar = layoutManager.characterIndexForGlyph(at: touchedGlyph)
        var range = NSRange()
        let attrs = attributedText!.attributes(at: touchedChar, effectiveRange: &range)
        if let urlstr = attrs[.link] as? String {
            return (range, URL(string: urlstr)!)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    public override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
        didSet {
            textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
            textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
            if let txt = attributedText {
                storage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: txt)
                storage!.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
                layoutManager.textStorage = storage
                textContainer.size = frame.size
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see `mxcl`, I give it a try, works great.

If you want to style your link appearance, use `NSAttributedString.Key.attachment` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I follow this version,

**Swift 4:**

```
import Foundation

class AELinkedClickableUILabel: UILabel {

    typealias YourCompletion = () -> Void

    var linkedRange: NSRange!
    var completion: YourCompletion?

    @objc func linkClicked(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

        if let completionBlock = completion {

            let textView = UITextView(frame: self.frame)
            textView.text = self.text
            textView.attributedText = self.attributedText
            let index = textView.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: sender.location(in: self),
                                                              in: textView.textContainer,
                                                              fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

            if linkedRange.lowerBound <= index && linkedRange.upperBound >= index {

                completionBlock()
            }
        }
    }

/**
 *  This method will be used to set an attributed text specifying the linked text with a
 *  handler when the link is clicked
 */
    public func setLinkedTextWithHandler(text:String, link: String, handler: @escaping ()->()) -> Bool {

        let attributextText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        let foundRange = attributextText.mutableString.range(of: link)

        if foundRange.location != NSNotFound {
            self.linkedRange = foundRange
            self.completion = handler
            attributextText.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: text, range: foundRange)
            self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(linkClicked(sender:))))
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**Call Example:**

```
button.setLinkedTextWithHandler(text: "This website (stackoverflow.com) is awesome", link: "stackoverflow.com") 
{
    // show popup or open to link
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a other solution:

I find a way to detect the link in a html text that you find from the internet you transform it into nsattributeString with :

```
func htmlAttributedString(fontSize: CGFloat = 17.0) -> NSAttributedString? {
            let fontName = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize).fontName
            let string = self.appending(String(format: "<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>", fontName, fontSize))
            guard let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }

            guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString (
                data: data,
                options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
            return html
        }
```

My method allows you to detect the hyperlink without having to specify them.

- first you create an extension of the tapgesturerecognizer :

  ```
  extension UITapGestureRecognizer {
  func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
      guard let attrString = label.attributedText else {
          return false
      }

      let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
      let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: .zero)
      let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attrString)

      layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
      textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

      textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
      textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
      textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
      let labelSize = label.bounds.size
      textContainer.size = labelSize

      let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
      let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
      let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
      let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)
      let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
      return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
  }
  ```

  }

then in you view controller you created a list of url and ranges to store all the links and the range that the attribute text contain:

```
var listurl : [String] = []
    var listURLRange : [NSRange] = []
```

to find the URL and the URLRange you can use :

```
    fun findLinksAndRange(attributeString : NSAttributeString){
        notification.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link , in: NSMakeRange(0, notification.length), options: [.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired]) { value, range, isStop in
                    if let value = value {
                        print("\(value) found at \(range.location)")
                        let stringValue = "\(value)"
                        listurl.append(stringValue)
                        listURLRange.append(range)
                    }
                }

            westlandNotifcationLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target : self, action: #selector(handleTapOnLabel(_:))))

    }
```

then you implementing the handle tap :

```
@objc func handleTapOnLabel(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        for index in 0..<listURLRange.count{
            if recognizer.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: westlandNotifcationLabel, inRange: listURLRange[index]) {
                goToWebsite(url : listurl[index])
            }
        }
    }

    func goToWebsite(url : String){
        if let websiteUrl = URL(string: url){
            if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(websiteUrl, options: [:],
                                          completionHandler: {
                                            (success) in
                                            print("Open \(websiteUrl): \(success)")
                })
            } else {
                let success = UIApplication.shared.openURL(websiteUrl)
                print("Open \(websiteUrl): \(success)")
            }
        }
    }
```

and here we go!

I hope this solution help you like it help me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm extending @samwize's answer to handle multi-line UILabel and give an example on using for a UIButton

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInButton(button: UIButton, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        guard let label = button.titleLabel else { return false }
        return didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label, inRange: targetRange)
    }

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.locationInView(label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                              (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake((locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x),
                                                         0 );
        // Adjust for multiple lines of text
        let lineModifier = Int(ceil(locationOfTouchInLabel.y / label.font.lineHeight)) - 1
        let rightMostFirstLinePoint = CGPointMake(labelSize.width, 0)
        let charsPerLine = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(rightMostFirstLinePoint, inTextContainer: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(locationOfTouchInTextContainer, inTextContainer: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        let adjustedRange = indexOfCharacter + (lineModifier * charsPerLine)

        return NSLocationInRange(adjustedRange, targetRange)
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution for a multi line UILabel, and it doesn't really work for me. The touch is always registered in the last line of my UILabel.

Comment: @ChristianSchober do you have custom fonts or line heights?

Comment: not really, we use the font HelveticaNeue and standard heights

Comment: not work when line break not on the right edge of label

Comment: I have default fonts but line spacing and didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For fully custom links, you'll need to use a UIWebView - you can intercept the calls out, so that you can go to some other part of your app instead when a link is pressed.

Comment: UIWebViews aren't that fast when allocating, so using a UILabel or UITextField library like FancyLabel or TTTAttributedLabel is better if you can get away with it. This is especially pertinent if you need clickable links incorporated in tableview cells etc.

Answer (score 2):

based on Charles Gamble answer, this what I used (I removed some lines that confused me and gave me wrong indexed) :

```
- (BOOL)didTapAttributedTextInLabel:(UILabel *)label inRange:(NSRange)targetRange TapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*) gesture{
    NSParameterAssert(label != nil);

    // create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];

    // configure layoutManager and textStorage
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    // configure textContainer for the label
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height)];

    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode;
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines;

    // find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInLabel = [gesture locationInView:label];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer]; //(move here, not sure it that matter that calling this line after textContainer is set

    NSInteger indexOfCharacter = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:locationOfTouchInLabel
                                                           inTextContainer:textContainer
                                  fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];
    if (NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a drop-in Objective-C category that enables clickable links in existing `UILabel.attributedText` strings, exploiting the existing `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute.

```
@interface UILabel (GSBClickableLinks) <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property BOOL enableLinks;
@end

#import <objc/runtime.h>
static const void *INDEX;
static const void *TAP;

@implementation UILabel (GSBClickableLinks)

- (void)setEnableLinks:(BOOL)enableLinks
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &TAP); // retreive tap
    if (enableLinks && !tap) { // add a gestureRegonzier to the UILabel to detect taps
        tap = [UITapGestureRecognizer.alloc initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openLink)];
        tap.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &TAP, tap, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); // save tap
    }
    self.userInteractionEnabled = enableLinks; // note - when false UILAbel wont receive taps, hence disable links
}

- (BOOL)enableLinks
{
    return (BOOL)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &TAP); // ie tap != nil
}

// First check whether user tapped on a link within the attributedText of the label.
// If so, then the our label's gestureRecogizer will subsequently fire, and open the corresponding NSLinkAttributeName.
// If not, then the tap will get passed along, eg to the enclosing UITableViewCell...
// Note: save which character in the attributedText was clicked so that we dont have to redo everything again in openLink.
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer != objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &TAP)) return YES; // dont block other gestures (eg swipe)

    // Re-layout the attributedText to find out what was tapped
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [NSTextContainer.alloc initWithSize:self.frame.size];
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.numberOfLines;
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = NSLayoutManager.new;
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [NSTextStorage.alloc initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    NSUInteger index = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self]
                                             inTextContainer:textContainer
                    fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &INDEX, @(index), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC); // save index

    return (BOOL)[self.attributedText attribute:NSLinkAttributeName atIndex:index effectiveRange:NULL]; // tapped on part of a link?
}

- (void)openLink
{
    NSUInteger index = [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &INDEX) unsignedIntegerValue]; // retrieve index
    NSURL *url = [self.attributedText attribute:NSLinkAttributeName atIndex:index effectiveRange:NULL];
    if (url && [UIApplication.sharedApplication canOpenURL:url]) [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:url];
}

@end
```

This would be a bit cleaner done via a UILabel subclass (ie none of the objc_getAssociatedObject mess), but if you are like me you prefer to avoid having to make unnecessary (3rd party) subclasses just to add some extra function to existing UIKit classes. Also, this has the beauty that it adds clickable-links to *any* existing UILabel, eg existing `UITableViewCells`!

I've tried to make it as minimally invasive as possible by using the existing `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute stuff already available in NSAttributedString. So its a simple as:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableAttributedString *myString = [NSMutableAttributedString.alloc initWithString:@"This string has a clickable link: "];
[myString appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString.alloc initWithString:@"click here" attributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName:myURL}]];
...
myLabel.attributedText = myString;
myLabel.enableLinks = YES; // yes, that's all! :-)
```

Basically, it works by adding a `UIGestureRecognizer` to your UILabel. The hard work is done in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`, which re-layouts the attributedText string to find out which character was tapped on. If this character was part of a NSLinkAttributeName then the gestureRecognizer will subsequently fire, retrieve the corresponding URL (from the NSLinkAttributeName value), and open the link per the usual `[UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:url]` process.

Note - by doing all this in `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`, if you dont happen to tap on a link in the label, the event is passed along. So, for example, your UITableViewCell will capture taps on links, but otherwise behave normally (select cell, unselect, scroll, ...).

I've put this in a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/tiritea/GSBClickableLinks).
Adapted from Kai Burghardt's SO posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349725).

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible albeit very confusing to figure out at first. I will go a step further and show you how you can even click on any area in the text as well.

With this method you can have UI Label tha is:

- Multiline Friendly
- Autoshrink Friendly
- Clickable Friendly (yes, even individual characters)
- Swift 5

**Step 1:**

Make the UILabel have the properties for Line Break of '**Truncate Tail**' and set a **minimum font scale**.

If you are unfamiliar with font scale just remember this rule:

***minimumFontSize/defaultFontSize = fontscale***

In my case I wanted `7.2` to be the minimum font size and my starting font size was `36`. Therefore, `7.2 / 36 = 0.2`

[image]

**Step 2:**

**If you do not care about the labels being clickable and just wanted a working multiline label you are done!**

HOWEVER, if you want the *labels to be clickable* read on...

Add this following extension I created

```
extension UILabel {

    func setOptimalFontSize(maxFontSize:CGFloat,text:String){
        let width = self.bounds.size.width

        var font_size:CGFloat = maxFontSize //Set the maximum font size.
        var stringSize = NSString(string: text).size(withAttributes: [.font : self.font.withSize(font_size)])
        while(stringSize.width > width){
            font_size = font_size - 1
            stringSize = NSString(string: text).size(withAttributes: [.font : self.font.withSize(font_size)])
        }

        self.font = self.font.withSize(font_size)//Forcefully change font to match what it would be graphically.
    }
}
```

It's used like this (just replace `<Label>` with your actual label name):

```
<Label>.setOptimalFontSize(maxFontSize: 36.0, text: formula)
```

This extension is needed because auto shrink does **NOT change the 'font' property of the label** after it auto-shrinks so you have to deduce it by calculating it the same way it does by using .size(withAttributes) function which simulates what it's size would be with that particular font.

This is necessary because the solution for detecting where to click on the label requires the **exact font size to be known**.

**Step 3:**

Add the following extension:

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)

        let mutableAttribString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        mutableAttribString.addAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: label.font!], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: label.attributedText!.length))

        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 6
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
        mutableAttribString.addAttributes([.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle], range: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttribString.string.count))

        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: mutableAttribString)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        let labelSize = label.bounds.size

        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)

        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        //let textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                              //(labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)

        //let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                        // locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        print("IndexOfCharacter=",indexOfCharacter)

        print("TargetRange=",targetRange)
        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }

}
```

You will need to modify this extension for your particular multiline situation.  In my case you will notice that I use a paragraph style.

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 6
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
        mutableAttribString.addAttributes([.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle], range: NSMakeRange(0, mutableAttribString.string.count))
```

Make sure to **change this** in the extension to what you are actually using for your **line spacing** so that everything calculates correctly.

Step 4:

Add the gestureRecognizer to the label in `viewDidLoad` or where you think is appropriate like so (just replace `<Label>` with your label name again:

```
<Label>.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(tapLabel(gesture:))))
```

Here is a simplified example of my tapLabel function (just replace `<Label>` with your UILabel name):

```
@IBAction func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let text = <Label>.attributedText?.string else {
            return
        }

        let click_range = text.range(of: "(α/β)")

        if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: <Label>, inRange: NSRange(click_range!, in: text)) {
           print("Tapped a/b")
        }else {
           print("Tapped none")
        }
    }
```

Just a note in my example, my string is `BED = N * d * [ RBE + ( d / (α/β) ) ]`, so I was just getting the range of the `α/β` in this case.  You could add "\n" to the string to add a newline and whatever text you wanted after and test this to find a string on the next line and it will still find it and detect the click correctly!

That's it! You are done.  Enjoy a **multiline** *clickable* label.

Answer (score 1):

Create the class with the following .h and .m files. In the .m file there is the following function

```
 - (void)linkAtPoint:(CGPoint)location
```

Inside this function we will check the ranges of substrings for which we need to give actions. Use your own logic to put your ranges.

And following is the usage of the subclass

```
TaggedLabel *label = [[TaggedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[self.view addSubview:label];
label.numberOfLines = 0;
NSMutableAttributedString *attributtedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString : @"My name is @jjpp" attributes : @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10],}];                                                                                                                                                                              
//Do not forget to add the font attribute.. else it wont work.. it is very important
[attributtedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                        value:[UIColor redColor]
                        range:NSMakeRange(11, 5)];//you can give this range inside the .m function mentioned above
```

following is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TaggedLabel : UILabel<NSLayoutManagerDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong)NSLayoutManager *layoutManager;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSTextContainer *textContainer;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSTextStorage *textStorage;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *tagsArray;
@property(readwrite, copy) tagTapped nameTagTapped;

@end
```

following is the .m file

```
#import "TaggedLabel.h"
@implementation TaggedLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
 self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
 if (self)
 {
  self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 }
return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
 self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self)
{
 self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
return self;
}

- (void)setupTextSystem
{
 _layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
 _textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeZero];
 _textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
 // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
 [_layoutManager addTextContainer:_textContainer];
 [_textStorage addLayoutManager:_layoutManager];
 // Configure textContainer
 _textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
 _textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
 _textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0;
 self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 self.textContainer.size = self.bounds.size;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 if (!_layoutManager)
 {
  [self setupTextSystem];
 }
 // Get the info for the touched link if there is one
 CGPoint touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
 [self linkAtPoint:touchLocation];
}

- (void)linkAtPoint:(CGPoint)location
{
 // Do nothing if we have no text
 if (_textStorage.string.length == 0)
 {
  return;
 }
 // Work out the offset of the text in the view
 CGPoint textOffset = [self calcGlyphsPositionInView];
 // Get the touch location and use text offset to convert to text cotainer coords
 location.x -= textOffset.x;
 location.y -= textOffset.y;
 NSUInteger touchedChar = [_layoutManager glyphIndexForPoint:location inTextContainer:_textContainer];
 // If the touch is in white space after the last glyph on the line we don't
 // count it as a hit on the text
 NSRange lineRange;
 CGRect lineRect = [_layoutManager lineFragmentUsedRectForGlyphAtIndex:touchedChar effectiveRange:&lineRange];
 if (CGRectContainsPoint(lineRect, location) == NO)
 {
  return;
 }
 // Find the word that was touched and call the detection block
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(11, 5);//for this example i'm hardcoding the range here. In a real scenario it should be iterated through an array for checking all the ranges
    if ((touchedChar >= range.location) && touchedChar < (range.location + range.length))
    {
     NSLog(@"range-->>%@",self.tagsArray[i][@"range"]);
    }
}

- (CGPoint)calcGlyphsPositionInView
{
 CGPoint textOffset = CGPointZero;
 CGRect textBounds = [_layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:_textContainer];
 textBounds.size.width = ceil(textBounds.size.width);
 textBounds.size.height = ceil(textBounds.size.height);

 if (textBounds.size.height < self.bounds.size.height)
 {
  CGFloat paddingHeight = (self.bounds.size.height - textBounds.size.height) / 2.0;
  textOffset.y = paddingHeight;
 }

 if (textBounds.size.width < self.bounds.size.width)
 {
  CGFloat paddingHeight = (self.bounds.size.width - textBounds.size.width) / 2.0;
  textOffset.x = paddingHeight;
 }
 return textOffset;
 }

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop-in solution as a category on `UILabel` (this assumes your `UILabel` uses an attributed string with some `NSLinkAttributeName` attributes in it):

```
@implementation UILabel (Support)

- (BOOL)openTappedLinkAtLocation:(CGPoint)location {
  CGSize labelSize = self.bounds.size;

  NSTextContainer* textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeZero];
  textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
  textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
  textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.numberOfLines;
  textContainer.size = labelSize;

  NSLayoutManager* layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
  [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

  NSTextStorage* textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
  [textStorage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:self.font range:NSMakeRange(0, textStorage.length)];
  [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

  CGRect textBoundingBox = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
  CGPoint textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                            (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
  CGPoint locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(location.x - textContainerOffset.x, location.y - textContainerOffset.y);
  NSInteger indexOfCharacter = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:locationOfTouchInTextContainer inTextContainer:textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nullptr];
  if (indexOfCharacter >= 0) {
    NSURL* url = [textStorage attribute:NSLinkAttributeName atIndex:indexOfCharacter effectiveRange:nullptr];
    if (url) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
      return YES;
    }
  }
  return NO;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

This generic method works too !

```
func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        guard let strAttributedText = self.attributedText else {
            return false
        }

        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: strAttributedText)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = Constants.lineFragmentPadding
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = self.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = CGSize(width: labelSize.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = gesture.location(in: self)

        let xCordLocationOfTouchInTextContainer = locationOfTouchInLabel.x
        let yCordLocationOfTouchInTextContainer = locationOfTouchInLabel.y
        let locOfTouch = CGPoint(x: xCordLocationOfTouchInTextContainer ,
                                 y: yCordLocationOfTouchInTextContainer)

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locOfTouch, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        guard let strLabel = text else {
            return false
        }

        let charCountOfLabel = strLabel.count

        if indexOfCharacter < (charCountOfLabel - 1) {
            return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

And you can call the method with

```
let text = yourLabel.text
let termsRange = (text as NSString).range(of: fullString)
if yourLabel.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer, inRange: termsRange) {
            showCorrespondingViewController()
        }
```

Comment: In your example of using your code, where does `UITapGestureRecognizer` come from? Is it an outlet? A property you setup?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/HamGuy/4c5c51b044264aef4eeb991ce97c9dcb) is my answer based on @Luca Davanzo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34772457/1096059), override the `touchesBegan` event instead of a tap gesture:

```
import UIKit

public protocol TapableLabelDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
   func tapableLabel(_ label: TapableLabel, didTapUrl url: String, atRange range: NSRange)
}

public class TapableLabel: UILabel {

private var links: [String: NSRange] = [:]
private(set) var layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
private(set) var textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
private(set) var textStorage = NSTextStorage() {
    didSet {
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
    }
}

public weak var delegate: TapableLabelDelegate?

public override var attributedText: NSAttributedString? {
    didSet {
        if let attributedText = attributedText {
            textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
        } else {
            textStorage = NSTextStorage()
            links = [:]
        }
    }
}

public override var lineBreakMode: NSLineBreakMode {
    didSet {
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
    }
}

public override var numberOfLines: Int {
    didSet {
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines
    }
}


public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    textContainer.size = bounds.size
}


/// addLinks
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - text: text of link
///   - url: link url string
public func addLink(_ text: String, withURL url: String) {
    guard let theText = attributedText?.string as? NSString else {
        return
    }

    let range = theText.range(of: text)

    guard range.location !=  NSNotFound else {
        return
    }

    links[url] = range
}

private func setup() {
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines  = numberOfLines
}

public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let locationOfTouch = touches.first?.location(in: self) else {
        return
    }

    textContainer.size = bounds.size
    let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: locationOfTouch, in: textContainer)

    for (urlString, range) in links {
        if NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, range), let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            delegate?.tapableLabel(self, didTapUrl: urlString, atRange: range)
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified @timbroder code to handle multiple line correctly for swift4.2

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                          y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: (locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x),
                                                     y: 0 );
        // Adjust for multiple lines of text
        let lineModifier = Int(ceil(locationOfTouchInLabel.y / label.font.lineHeight)) - 1
        let rightMostFirstLinePoint = CGPoint(x: labelSize.width, y: 0)
        let charsPerLine = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: rightMostFirstLinePoint, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        let adjustedRange = indexOfCharacter + (lineModifier * charsPerLine)
        var newTargetRange = targetRange
        if lineModifier > 0 {
            newTargetRange.location = targetRange.location+(lineModifier*Int(ceil(locationOfTouchInLabel.y)))
        }
        return NSLocationInRange(adjustedRange, newTargetRange)
    }
}
```

UILabel Code

```
let tapAction = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapLabel(gesture:)))

let quote = "For full details please see our privacy policy and cookie policy."
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: quote)

let string1: String = "privacy policy", string2: String = "cookie policy"

// privacy policy
let rangeString1 = quote.range(of: string1)!
let indexString1: Int = quote.distance(from: quote.startIndex, to: rangeString1.lowerBound)
attributedString.addAttributes(
            [.font: <UIfont>,
             .foregroundColor: <UI Color>,
             .underlineStyle: 0, .underlineColor:UIColor.clear
        ], range: NSRange(location: indexString1, length: string1.count));

// cookie policy
let rangeString2 = quote.range(of: string2)!
let indexString2: Int = quote.distance(from: quote.startIndex, to: rangeString2.lowerBound )

attributedString.addAttributes(
            [.font: <UIfont>,
             .foregroundColor: <UI Color>,
             .underlineStyle: 0, .underlineColor:UIColor.clear
        ], range: NSRange(location: indexString2, length: string2.count));

let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 200, width: 375, height: 100)
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
label.addGestureRecognizer(tapAction)
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Code to recognise the Tap

```
 @objc
  func tapLabel(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: <UILabel>, inRange: termsLabelRange {
            print("Terms of service")
     } else if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label:<UILabel> inRange: privacyPolicyLabelRange) {
            print("Privacy policy")
     } else {
            print("Tapped none")
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We use the convenient solution from [zekel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29352519/2439941) with the `UITapGestureRecognizer` category.
This uses `NSTextContainer`, like many answers to this question do.

However, this returned wrong character indexes. Apparently because `NSTextContainer` was missing information about the font style, as indicated by these other posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34238382/2439941
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47358270/2439941

After changing:

```
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];
```

To:

```
// Apply the font of the label to the attributed text: 
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.new;
paragraphStyle.alignment = self.label.textAlignment;
[attributedText addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: label.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle} 
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, label.attributedText.string.length)];

// Init with attributed text from label:
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedText];
```

The result was significantly better, the tap area was now correctly starting at the first character of our target string. But the last character returned still `NO`. We expected that this was related to the fact that our target string has attributes to set the font weight to `UIFontWeightSemibold`. While the above code improvement applies `label.font` on the **entire** string, which has a regular weight.

To solve this we improved the above code snippet even further, by iterating over **all** attributed ranges, in order to support multiple font styles in the text:

```
// According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47358270/2439941 it's required to apply the paragraph style and font of the UILabel.
// However, the attributed string might contain font formatting as well, e.g. to emphasize a word in a different font style.
// Therefor copy all attributes:
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];
[label.attributedText enumerateAttributesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, label.attributedText.length)
                                         options:0
                                      usingBlock:^(NSDictionary<NSAttributedStringKey,id> * _Nonnull attrs, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    // Add each attribute:
    [attributedText addAttributes:attrs
                            range:range];
    
    // In case the attributes of this range do NOT contain a font specifier, apply the font from the UILabel:
    if (![attrs objectForKey:NSFontAttributeName]) {
        [attributedText addAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : label.font }
                                range:range];
    }
}];

// Init the storage with the font attributed text:
NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedText];
```

Now the method returns `YES` for **every** character in the semi-bold string range, which is the expected result.

Comment: Still not working for me

Comment: Can you help me out in it? @Martijn

Answer (score 0):

**TAGS** #Swift2.0

I take inspiration on - excellent - @NAlexN's answer and I decide to write by myself a wrapper of UILabel.
I also tried [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) but I can't make it works.

Hope you can appreciate this code, any suggestions are welcome!

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol TappableLabelDelegate {
    optional func tappableLabel(tabbableLabel: TappableLabel, didTapUrl: NSURL, atRange: NSRange)
}

/// Represent a label with attributed text inside.
/// We can add a correspondence between a range of the attributed string an a link (URL)
/// By default, link will be open on the external browser @see 'openLinkOnExternalBrowser'

class TappableLabel: UILabel {

    // MARK: - Public properties -

    var links: NSMutableDictionary = [:]
    var openLinkOnExternalBrowser = true
    var delegate: TappableLabelDelegate?

    // MARK: - Constructors -

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.enableInteraction()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.enableInteraction()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func enableInteraction() {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("didTapOnLabel:")))
    }

    // MARK: - Public methods -

    /**
    Add correspondence between a range and a link.

    - parameter url:   url.
    - parameter range: range on which couple url.
    */
    func addLink(url url: String, atRange range: NSRange) {
        self.links[url] = range
    }

    // MARK: - Public properties -

    /**
    Action rised on user interaction on label.

    - parameter tapGesture: gesture.
    */
    func didTapOnLabel(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let labelSize = self.bounds.size;

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSizeZero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: self.attributedText!)

        // configure textContainer for the label
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.numberOfLines
        textContainer.size = labelSize;

        // configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = tapGesture.locationInView(self)

        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRectForTextContainer(textContainer)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
            (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
            locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(locationOfTouchInTextContainer,
            inTextContainer:textContainer,
            fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        for (url, value) in self.links {
            if let range = value as? NSRange {
                if NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, range) {
                    let url = NSURL(string: url as! String)!
                    if self.openLinkOnExternalBrowser {
                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
                    }
                    self.delegate?.tappableLabel?(self, didTapUrl: url, atRange: range)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In my case, there was a strange result with only one line text to calculate the index of character, it always return `0` cause that `locationOfTouchInTextContainer.x`  was negative. I try to use `let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: locationOfTouch, in: textContainer)` instead, and works well.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)didTapAttributedTextInLabel:(UILabel *)label inRange:(NSRange)targetRange{
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [NSLayoutManager new];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeZero];
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:label.attributedText];

    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode;
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines;
    CGSize labelSize = label.bounds.size;
    textContainer.size = labelSize;

    CGPoint locationOfTouchInLabel = [self locationInView:label];
    CGRect textBoundingBox = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
    CGPoint textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                              (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                         locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
    NSUInteger indexOfCharacter =[layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:locationOfTouchInTextContainer inTextContainer:textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];

    return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Xamarin.iOS c# implementation based on Kedar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34014655/15186).

MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme implementation with `ShouldInteractWithUrl` override:

```
// Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112932/15186
internal class MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme : UITextView, IUITextViewDelegate
{
    public MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme(Foundation.NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme(Foundation.NSObjectFlag t) : base(t)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme(CoreGraphics.CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme(CoreGraphics.CGRect frame, NSTextContainer textContainer) : base(frame, textContainer)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        Delegate = this;
    }

    [Export("textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:")]
    public new bool ShouldInteractWithUrl(UITextView textView, NSUrl URL, NSRange characterRange)
    {
        if (URL.Scheme.CompareTo(@"username") == 0)
        {
            // Launch the Activity
            return false;
        }
        // The system will handle the URL
        return base.ShouldInteractWithUrl(textView, URL, characterRange);
    }
}
```

Converted objective-C code in c# becomes:

```
MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme uiHabitTile = new MyClickableTextViewWithCustomUrlScheme();
uiHabitTile.Selectable = true;
uiHabitTile.ScrollEnabled = false;
uiHabitTile.Editable = false;

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/34014655/15186
string wholeTitle = @"This is an example by marcelofabri";

NSMutableAttributedString attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString(wholeTitle);
attributedString.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.Link,
   new NSString("username://marcelofabri"),
   attributedString.Value.RangeOfString(@"marcelofabri")
);
NSMutableDictionary<NSString, NSObject> linkAttributes = new NSMutableDictionary<NSString, NSObject>();
linkAttributes[UIStringAttributeKey.ForegroundColor] = UIColor.Green;
linkAttributes[UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineColor] = UIColor.LightGray;
linkAttributes[UIStringAttributeKey.UnderlineStyle] = new NSNumber((short)NSUnderlineStyle.PatternSolid);

uiHabitTile.AttributedText = attributedString;
```

Make sure to set Editable = false and Selectable = true to be able to click the link.

Also ScrollEnabled = true allows the textview to size its height correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.2**

I've found several issues with multiline text labels in previous answers, so I give my final working solution.

It solves the issues with multilines and text alignment.

```
    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize
        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        let textAligmentOffset = aligmentOffset(for: label)
        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * textAligmentOffset - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                          y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * textAligmentOffset - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: (locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x),
                                                     y: 0 )
        // Adjust for multiple lines of text
        let lineModifier = Int(floor(locationOfTouchInLabel.y / label.font.lineHeight)) - 1
        let rightMostFirstLinePoint = CGPoint(x: labelSize.width,
                                              y: 0)
        let charsPerLine = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: rightMostFirstLinePoint, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        let adjustedRange = indexOfCharacter + (lineModifier * charsPerLine)
        return NSLocationInRange(adjustedRange, targetRange)
    }
    
    private func aligmentOffset(for label: UILabel) -> CGFloat {
        switch label.textAlignment {
        case .left, .natural, .justified:
            return 0.0
        case .center:
            return 0.5
        case .right:
            return 1.0
        @unknown default:
            return 0.0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS 15, SwiftUI comes with built-in support Markdown markup language so text in Markdown:

```
Text("You can [click this link](https://www.example.com) to visit the website.")
```

[image]

Or as a simplest example with using [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui) you can do it like this:

```
        HStack() {
            Text("Open the")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Link(destination: URL(string: "https://www.example.com/TOS.html")!) {
                Text("link")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .underline()
            }
            Text("in browser")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

```
    NSString *string = name;
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSDataDetector *detector =
    [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeLink | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber
                                    error:&error];
    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:string
                                         options:0
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
    {
        if (([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber))
        {
            NSString *phoneNumber = [match phoneNumber];
            NSLog(@" Phone Number is :%@",phoneNumber);
            label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber;
        }

        if(([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink))
        {
            NSURL *email = [match URL];
            NSLog(@"Email is  :%@",email);
            label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
        }

        if (([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink))
        {
            NSURL *url = [match URL];
            NSLog(@"URL is  :%@",url);
            label.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
        }
    }

    label.text =name;
}
```

Comment: Event though there is a question, your ANSWER should contain some explanation to your code. This would make your answer better. Probably you would get some up-votes as well ;-)