# URL or email address as link in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UILabel tha contains a URL (ie www.google.com). Is there a way to display the label as URL so the User can tap on the URL for Safari to open it?

Same question I have for a mailto item (ie info@google.com) to open mail with a new email to that address

thanks in advance

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/clickable-links-in-uilabel) question has the answer you are looking for.