# UITableView how to make clickable links

Tags: uitableview, clickable

could anyone point me in the direction on how to do this please? i have made a twiter app which i would like to open links from the users timeline. i have sourced the code on how to open the link in my webvie but i do not know hot to make the links clickable.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you need: http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/

More infos is this SO discussion: [Create tap-able "links" in the NSAttributedString of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/clickable-links-in-uilabel)

Comment: What I've found out is I need to open a detailview from my uitableview then implement the clickable link. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Sure. If you like an answer, an up-vote and/or "accepting it" is appreciated.