# Turning label into hyperlink Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, uilabel

I have a UILabel which text is www.google.com. Now if someone moves the cursor on the text and press it the google's homepage should be open. Is it possible? please explain how....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the direction you need to go see: [Create tap-able "links" in the NSAttributedString of a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/clickable-links-in-uilabel) and then go to: http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/