# How to enable links in text

Tags: objective-c, text, hyperlink

I have the following implementation to display the text. However, I am unable to click on a link in the text "www.google.com". How can I change my implementation such that if a link exists, I will be able to click on it and it redirects me to the web page?

```
NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.answerForCell.text];
CGFloat answerLabelHeight = [CustomCell getHeightOfLabel:answer ofFontSize:ANSWER_FONT_SIZE withConstraint: ANSWER_CONSTRAINT];
UILabel *thisAnswerLabel = (UILabel*)[self.contentView viewWithTag:ANSWERLABEL_TAG];
[thisAnswerLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_TEXT_LEFT_MARGIN + CELL_AVATAR_WIDTH + CELL_SPACING, currentYAxisValue, CELL_ANSWER_WIDTH, answerLabelHeight)];
thisAnswerLabel.text = answer;
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clickable links in UILabel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/clickable-links-in-uilabel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabels do not support hyperlinking. Instead consider using a [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to display the text in the answer.

Another way to do it would be to use [regular expressions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to check if the text contains a link, and in that case turn the whole label into a button that the user can click/tap. To me this seems like a setting where a web view is preferred though, since I'm guessing the answer could be a long text.