# UIScrollView with "Links"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, scrollview

Guys!

So, I have an UIScrollView. In this Scroll View, I want to have a text like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.

In this UIScrollView, I want to have a link in each phrase, so the user can touch in this phrase and an IBAction/void is accomplished.

Do you understand me?

Thanks a lot, 

Alberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked about this. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/clickable-links-in-uilabel) suit your needs? It works with individual UILabels. If you have multiple links in your text, perhaps embedded hyperlinks are what you need. For this I would use [LRLinkableLabel](https://github.com/lukeredpath/LRLinkableLabel).