# ios: How to set urllink in uilabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Hi friends My project is based o parsing json datas from url, i have parsed datas and displayed in screen but my problem is, some data i received from json is in the from of link. `but when i viewd that in label it looks like normal data, not as link`. `i need to view it as link`. when user clicks the link it has go to that respective webpage in mobile browser. Please help me on how to do it. Here is the code which i tried

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SuccessCell";
    SuccessListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.title.text = (NSString *)[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.linklabel.text = (NSString *)[array3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//Here i need show this data as link
    cell.datetime.text = @"Success Story URL(Pictures,Videos,etc.);";
    cell.desc.text = (NSString *)[array11 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Please Help me how to do this Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why you are not using UIButton instead of a UILabel? On press of a button you can directly open that link in browser.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581714/detect-urls-in-uilabel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **UITextView** instead of **UILabel** if you click on it ,it will call delegate method ,check below code :

```
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(10,200, 300, 30);
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    textView.text=@" This is testing url here HTTP://WWW.GOOGLE.COM";
    textView.editable = NO;
    textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

    textView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textView];

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)
{
    return YES;
}
```

**Note:** it support only >= **IOS 7**.

may it will help you.

happy coding...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try the control [FancyLabel](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/). It's exactly what you need.

If you get stuck with it, you can try [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) - that's much more simple.

Comment: i didnt understood how to invoke those fancy labels in ios. little clear please

Comment: well, I've posted a link to another control - try it!;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIWebView` and set it's `dataDetectorTypes` property or use a button and on click event try using below code,

```
-(IBAction)openLink:(UIButton *)sender
{
  NSString*myurl=sender.titleLabel.text;
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myurl];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```