# iOS tweet a hyperlink

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter, tweets

Instead of adding the URL to the tweet like this:

```
[tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.url]];
```

is it possible to have words highlighted blue and linked to a website when a user clicks on them much like is often seen on this website? I've looked into fancy label for iOS but this is for a label, and I'm afraid that won't work for a tweet.

Thanks.

Comment: are the tweets being displayed on the user's iPad or simply sent out from the user's iPad? do you want these tweets to appear in an app that you authored or some other app?

Comment: well I'm using the SLComposeViewController, so it's actually sending out the tweet. So they will show up on any Twitter app, but not mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about "any Twitter app", you don't have any control as to how they are displaying Twitter feeds.

The only apps where you can use [solutions like "FancyLabel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/clickable-links-in-uilabel) or [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) are apps that you yourself write the code for and control.

Comment: what about Twitter's official app?

Comment: Same thing, as far as I know.  No way to format a tweet in such a way where it gets rendered within Twitter's official app the exact way you want it.  Twitter would have to change code on their side to support this.  [You should file this as a feature request with them](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.twitter.com%2Fgroups%2F32-something-s-not-working&text=Twitter%20Help%20Center%20%7C%20Something's%20not%20working&tw_p=tweetbutton&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.twitter.com%2Fgroups%2F32-something-s-not-working&via=support).