# Add UITapGestureRecognizer to NSAttributed Text with a range

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I have an attributed string set up like this:

```
var range = (showStr as NSString).rangeOfString(spellingStr)
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:showStr)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: ezGreen, range: range)
```

and i would like to add a tap gesture just to the range that i set to green.

Is there an attribute for touches? How would i set the tap gesture just for the `spellingStr` part?

***EDIT***

all my code for that label and string is below:

```
var showStr:NSString = "Showing results for \(searchT)."
println("SearchTerm:\(searchT)")
showingLabel.textColor = .blackColor()

var range = (showStr as NSString).rangeOfString(searchT)
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:showStr)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: ezGreen , range: range)

showingLabel.attributedText = attributedString
showingLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
showingLabel.numberOfLines = 0
showingLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
var showHeight:CGFloat = heightForView(showingLabel.text!, UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17), maxLabelWidth)
showingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, heightOfCor, maxLabelWidth, showHeight)
heightOfCor += showHeight
bgBlack.addSubview(showingLabel)
```

Comment: This might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680724/how-can-i-detect-taps-on-a-particular-part-substring-of-a-uilabel

Comment: This may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/clickable-links-in-uilabel

Comment: @Glynbeard the problem i have with that solution is i don't want to recreate a label to click, because the string can be very different each time.

Comment: So, let me clarify sth. You want to be able to tap on some parts of the string in `UITextView` and be able to handle the event?

Comment: @SikhapolSaijit Exactly, except it's a `UILabel`

Comment: All of the code you've provided relates to the model (the string), and not the view (the UILabel). Could you add the related UILabel as well?

Comment: @A.R.Younce added, sorry i missed that

Comment: This seems to provide a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332283/detecting-taps-on-attributed-text-in-a-uitextview-on-ios-7

Comment: @inVINCEable If it's possible for you to use `UITextView` instead (you can disable editing which will make it undistinguishable to the user), you can follow the answers provided by @edwardmp to achieve what you want easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done it by just creating a UIButton and setting it to the exact frame of that line of text.

Here's an example of how to do it in objective-c:

```
NSRange range = [self.textView.text rangeOfString:@"The string of text you want to tap"];
self.textView.selectedRange = range;
UITextRange *textRange = [self.textView selectedTextRange];
CGRect textRect = [self.textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
CGRect convertedRect = [self.view convertRect:textRect fromView:self.textView];

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:convertedRect];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(textTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

NOTE: prior to calling this, you should have already setup your attributed string and added it to your UITextView. Also, ensure you allow selection inside your textView (but disable userInteraction if you dont want highlights etc)

[image]