# How to do clickable string in swift ?

Tags: swift, click, uilabel

I want to clickable string. like :

By creating an account, you agree to the ABC **Terms of Service** and **Privacy Policy**.

I want to click event Terms of Service , Privacy Policy.

My app support also multi language. How can I do this with multi

language any advice please ?

Comment: Have you tried to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `true` on the label?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034592/add-a-click-event-to-some-text-in-ios-nsstring

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a UILabel clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658521/how-to-make-a-uilabel-clickable)

Answer (score 2):

This solution should work for Swift 4

```
class YourClassViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var terms: UITextView!

let termsAndConditionsURL = "http://www.example.com/terms";
let privacyURL = "http://www.example.com/privacy";

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.terms.delegate = self
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "termsString".localized())
    var foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: "terms_and_conditions".localized())
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: termsAndConditionsURL, range: foundRange)
    foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: "Privacy".localized())
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: privacyURL, range: foundRange)
    terms.attributedText = attributedString
}


func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    if (URL.absoluteString == termsAndConditionsURL) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Terms", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if (URL.absoluteString == privacyURL) {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Conditions", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    return false
 }
}
```

Have a look that I use the localized extension from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29384360/4420355

```
extension String {
    func localized(withComment:String = "") -> String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: withComment)
    }
}
```

In my projects I prefer this pod https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift

You have to deposit your text strings in your localizable for multi language. 
For a complete tutorial have a look at https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881

```
//english
"terms_and_conditions" = "Terms and Condition";
"privacyURL" = "Privacy";
"termsString" =  "By using this app you agree to our Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy";

//german
"terms_and_conditions" = "Geschäftsbedingungen";
"privacy_url" = "Datenschutz";
"termsString" =  "Wenn du diese App verwendest, stimmst du dem Datenschutz und den Geschäftsbedigungen zu";
```

If you need different links for the privacy and the terms you can add them to localizable too.

In this solution you handle multi language in a very easy way.