# Get right point of glyph in NSLayoutManager with linebreak-mode enabled

Tags: ios, swift, nstextcontainer, nsparagraphstyle

I'm trying to get an actual point of selected character in `NSTextContainer`:

```
func handleTouch(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
   var location = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self)
   let startPoint = self.layoutManager.locationForGlyphAtIndex(0)
   location = CGPoint(x: location.x - startPoint.x, y: location.y - startPoint.y)
   var fraction: CGFloat = 0
   let index = self.layoutManager.glyphIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph: &fraction)
}
```

And it works works as it should, UNTIL first linebreak set by

```
NSParagraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 2
```

Every hyphen moves index for one point and `glyphIndexForPoint` get wrong index. How to get right index with linebreak-mode enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the similar function [characterIndexForPoint(_:inTextContainer:fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/characterIndexForPoint:inTextContainer:fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:)

For more details, you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349725/character-index-at-touch-point-for-uilabel)