# Hyperlinks in a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uitextview

I am trying to create a `UITextView` with a `hyperlink` so that when the user clicks on the link, they are taken to `safari`  to open the webpage. I have read on link detectors for a `textview` but those samples always show link detection working if an actual url is present in the text (ie. [www.google.com](http://google.com)). I want it to be regular text that, when clicked, opens an associated URL. (ie. Google is the text and when clicked, opens up a url [www.google.com](http://google.com)). How can I accomplish this in iOS7/8?

Comment: Use `NSAttributedString` and `NSLinkgAttributeName`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `NSAttributedString`

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Google" 
                                                                       attributes:@{ NSLinkAttributeName: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] }];
self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Sure, you can set just a portion of the text to be the link. Please read more about the `NSAttributedString` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/AttributedStrings.html).

If you want to have more control and do something before opening the link. You can set the delegate to the `UITextView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...
    self.textView.delegate = self; // self must conform to UITextViewDelegate protocol
}

...

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange {
    // Do whatever you want here
    NSLog(@"%@", URL); // URL is an instance of NSURL of the tapped link
    return YES; // Return NO if you don't want iOS to open the link
}
```

Comment: Just a quick followup: How can I get the ability that, when tapped, I get back the url that was tapped so I can send a web request? For ex. tapping Google would activate some selector which will pass the NSURL www.google.com)?

Comment: Set `self` (or whatever you want) to the `UITextView`'s delegate. Then implement `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:`. I'll update my answer to reflect this question.

Comment: What if i want to handle the link opening myself or want to do something else with the link (such as passing it to another object to initiate a network request). Ideally, I would want to get back the url of the text i just clicked on. How can i do that?

Comment: In `- textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` you get the URL (an instance of `NSURL`) that was tapped. You can do anything with it. Just return `NO` in that delegate method to prevent _iOS_ from opening the link.

Comment: Just in case `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` is `deprecated` and replaced with `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:interaction:`

Answer (score 20):

## Swift 3, iOS10 , Xcode 9

@sikhapol's answer is really nice if you knew exactly the words you want to parse like "word dictionary" somehow

it's all about the string itself that displayed
in UITextView

**My solution is based on the text rendering**
if you make the UITextView render HTML tags you may use  href  tag

**Here is some Code references you may use**

first, you need to configure UITextView from interface builder or form code
to

1. Selectable
2. Data detectores

## Note:  do not make the textview editable

**Interface builder**

[image]

**programmatically**

```
         let htmlData = NSString(string: "go to <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> and search for it").data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)


        let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        yourUIViewView.isSelectable = true
        yourUIViewView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
        yourUIViewView.attributedText = attributedString
        yourUIViewView.delegate = self
```

for the UITextViewDelegate

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    
       // check for the url string for performing your own custom actions here
      let urlString = URL.absoluteString
    
       // Return NO if you don't want iOS to open the link
        return true
     }
```

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date way to do this: `let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data:  Data("some <em>cool</em> text".utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)`

Answer (score 13):

A nifty little extension that I wrote and use (Swift 4.2, tested on iOS 12.1)

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    func replace(placeholder: String, with hyperlink: String, url: String) -> NSAttributedString {
        let mutableAttr = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self)

        let hyperlinkAttr = NSAttributedString(string: hyperlink, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.link: URL(string: url)!])

        let placeholderRange = (self.string as NSString).range(of: placeholder)

        mutableAttr.replaceCharacters(in: placeholderRange, with: hyperlinkAttr)
        return mutableAttr
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//Set through code or through interface builder
footerText.isSelectable = true
footerText.dataDetectorTypes = .link

//Keeps the original formatting from xib or storyboard
footerText.text = "By continuing, you are indicating that you accept our @Terms@ and @Privacy@."
footerText.attributedText = footerText.attributedText?
        .replace(placeholder: "@Terms@", with: "Terms and Conditions", url: AppUrl.terms)
        .replace(placeholder: "@Privacy@", with: "Privacy Policy", url: AppUrl.privacy)
```

Comment: If you pass font of the textView to the extension function and add it to hyperlinkAttr, all text will have same font and size.

Comment: works fine but I haver to add:           textView.isEditable = false

Comment: I wanted to disable the text selection on textview as on tapping other part of string it opens selection controller which i don't want and if I set isSelectable = false then link is not clickable

Answer (score 1):

This code sample has two different links in the same label and URL color is set to avoid the default blue.

```
UITextView * textTerm = [UITextView new];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrRight = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Terms of Service"
                                                                       attributes:@{ NSLinkAttributeName: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] }];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrLeft = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Privacy Policy"
                                                                       attributes:@{ NSLinkAttributeName: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] }];
[attrRight appendAttributedString:attrLeft];
textTerm.attributedText = attrRight;
textTerm.editable = NO;
textTerm.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
textTerm.linkTextAttributes = [UIColor whiteColor];
textTerm.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want active substring in your UITextView then you can use my extended TextView... its short and simple. You can edit it as you want.

how to use (range = substring location):

```
[self.textView addTapActionWithRange:range withActionBlock:^{
      // anything you want to do - show something
}];
```

result: 
[image]

source code: https://github.com/marekmand/ActiveSubstringTextView

Answer (score 0):

Since the edit queue was full, I'll post my version of an answer here. It's based on Amr Angry's answer.

I'm using DispatchQueue.main.async { ... } since the app will crash if the NSAttributedString is running on a background thread.

```
guard let htmlData = NSString(string: "go to <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> and search for it").data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue) else { return }
    
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    do {

    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    yourUIViewView.isSelectable = true
    yourUIViewView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
    yourUIViewView.attributedText = attributedString
    yourUIViewView.delegate = self

    } catch {
        print("Cannot setup link with \(htmlData)!")
    }
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

    // Return NO if you don't want iOS to open the link
    return true
}
```