# Is it possible to make UILable clickable when you click on href using AttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I've succeeded to display `HTML` as attributed String in UILable.

### The problem is when that HtmlString is containing `href link` nothing happens when you click on that href like the screenshot.

[image]

html string example

```
"The Privacy Policy can be found <a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp\">here</a> "
```

my code

```
let stringHTMl = "The Privacy Policy can be found <a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp\">here</a> "
cell.textUILable.attributedText = stringHTMl.convertHtml()
```

extension for converting stringToattributesHTMLString

```
func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UITextView`. Solution with `UITextView` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46912637/6183888).

Also, You can add `textView.isEditable = false` to looks like `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0 or latest**

Yo can achieve it like this:

```
let tapAction = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:@selector(actionTapped(_:)))
cell.textUILable.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
cell.textUILable.addGestureRecognizer(tapAction)
```

Action Tapped Defination is

```
func actionTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // on tap text Label code here what you want to do
}
```

Do what ever you want to do in `actionTapped`