# How to add a "More" and "Less" text indicator in a expandable UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am a IOS learner. I was doing a sample project, in which i require "More" and "Less" text indicators in a `UILabel` for which i have added a `SingleTapGestureRecognizer` to expand and contract based on the text content.The text content comes from API and is dynamic.

[image: Required output]

[image: Required output]

Here i have attached the screen shot of my required output.(The screen shots are from android).

Also i resize the UILabel programmatically except the constraints(No Auto layout). the code  use for tap gesture is

In `viewDidLoad()`

```
let singleTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTapped")
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.enabled = true
        singleTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        lblAmneties.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGestureRecognizer)
```

the method is

```
var amnetiesClicked = false
func singleTapped()
{
    if(amnetiesClicked == false) { amnetiesClicked = true }
    else { amnetiesClicked = false }
    if(amnetiesClicked == true)
    {
        Amneties.sizeToFit()
        self.display()
    }
    else
    {
        if(self.Amneties.frame.size.height > 70 )
        {
            self.Amneties.frame.size.height = 70
            self.display()
        }
    }
}
```

Here `display()` is the method where i align all the contents of the view programmatically.

I have no idea on how to do it. 
I use xcode 7.1.1 Swift 2.0

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309247/add-read-more-to-the-end-of-uilabel

Comment: Thanks for your Response. But i don't know objective c and i am unable to convert the code to swift. Could you please give me the swift version of the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used TTTAttributed Label to do that https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel
It has a predefined method to do that.

Comment: Please refer the method you're using of this library