# Getting black screen except navigation Bar SWIFT

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift4

My all previous projects works fine with this simulator but now whenever i'm creating new ViewController in previous projects or in new project, then ViewController looks black except Nav Bar. I don't know what's the problem even i reset my simulator but nothing solve my problem,

i think this  problem seem to be so complicated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UINavigationController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Currently View Controller [**looks here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlzNu.png)

ScreenShot attached here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nrjk.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2USZi.png)

I will be very glad if any of them help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share code of your view controller?

Comment: updated my question, Didn't right any code

Comment: How are you configuring navigation bar? Where? In storyboard? If yes - can you provide screenshots of your storyboard?

Comment: @IvanSmetanin updated my question, as i have do nothing with my View controller

Comment: This is UINavigationController, where is view controller code

Comment: Have you added root view controller or initial view controller

Comment: this is initial view controller

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary waiting for your kind response.

Comment: This is a UINavigationController, not a UIViewController So you need to embed UIViewController with this UINavigationController

Comment: To put it another way, this line is wrong: `class ViewController: UINavigationController` There is _never_ a good reason to subclass UINavigationController.

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary you are right Man, I'm so duffer as i'm testing this Simulator in two projects at the same time with same coding mistake, Thanks for Helping. :)

Comment: @Ahtazaz, Welcome man

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary ok you can :)

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary can you help me this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309247/add-read-more-to-the-end-of-uilabel/32882378

Comment: @Ahtazaz: This is not your question and also has accepted the answer so you can try and how can I help you on this question, please explain

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary oK i'm creating new Question then you please help me it with, Thanks

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary i have created my new Question, see it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550035/add-read-more-read-less-to-the-end-of-uilabel-swift

Comment: @Ahtazaz: I have added my answer please check and let me know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary please see my comment there.

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary hi buddy, i have created new Question, need your help f you can, Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50561499/add-nav-bar-under-view-swift

Comment: @Ahtazaz: Let me check

Comment: Thanks for instant feedback :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a UINavigationController, not a UIViewController So you need to embed UIViewController with this UINavigationController.
That's why you are getting the black screen.

You need to embed UIViewController with this navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using `UINavigationController` as superclass of your `ViewController`. You can change superclass to `UIViewController` and embed your `ViewController` in `UINavigationController`.

**Updated code:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**Image that shows how you can embed your** `ViewController`:

[image]