# Issue with Navigation Items SWIFT

Tags: swift4

As i need to make Nav Bar transparent, Everything works fine But now NavBar Items are getting fade.

How can it be manage?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationItem.title = "Property Details"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.5

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why you have not embedded navigation controller on storyboard?

Comment: And can you show me your code where you redrect the controller?

Comment: because i'm calling this using pusnViewController()

Comment: without navigation controller how you using push?

Comment: In the code there is nothing, I'm managing it using constraints from storyboard

Comment: wait i have to go somewhere instantly, will discuss after 30 min.

Comment: Have you added navigation controller on the initial view controller?

Comment: yes i have added navigational controller in initial VC, i'm moving from one VC to other VC on the base of some condition, if condition is true then go to other VC that's i'm using using pushViewController() .

Comment: And also sending some data to other VC when condition is true

Comment: SO you don't need to add navigation view, it will auto come in the second view controller.

Comment: ok but then how to customize Nav bar like the image that is attached in my Question

Comment: you can customize your navigation bar. what do you want with your nav bar?

Comment: I need same View and navbar that is in the image, but using scrollview. And  Navbar should not move up and own while scrolling.

Comment: Have you understand what i want?

Comment: See updated Question

Comment: You can do it, man. You have to set the transparency for the navigation bar. You can set translucent for the navigation bar. and your view will under nav bar then you will get same effect

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary yeah got it, according to your instructions, see updated Question.

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary bro i have done it, but now the problem with Navigation Items, see my updated Question. Need help

Comment: Remove alpha for nav bar background color and for transparency follow my answer. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add navigation controller from storyboard on initial view controller or you have to add navigation controller whenever you present the controller.

Hope this will work for you

Remove alpha = 0.5 and for nav bar transparency you need to do this:

```
// This is color extension to get image from color
public extension UIColor {

    func convertImage() -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        context.setFillColor(self.cgColor)
        context.fill(rect)

        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
///This is tranceparent image which is get from color
let image = UIColor.init(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.2).convertImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
```

You need to add UIColor extension in your code and then add bottom two lines in your controller and you can adjust your faded background view using increase or decrease alpha in UIColor, Now I have set 0.2 alpha