# UILabel with specific words in color and User Interaction enabling them in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I would like to achieve something like the above. There are solutions asking to use a UIButton and place it next to the UILabel. However is that the only way? This solution will not be able to cater different screen size as the lines of text may be only 1 line for bigger size. Or is there a way to color a specific range of UILabel and enable touch for the specific characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add "...Read More" to the end of UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309247/add-read-more-to-the-end-of-uilabel)

Comment: place a UILabel or UITextView and when you tap on it change the constrain size so It can be toggable.

Comment: i am not trying to change the size of my UILabel...  i needed it to be user interaction = true for. a specific range of string and it's colored blue