# How add button in label?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I need to add a button at the end of the text to trigger an alert. The text can be in several lines  **How can I do that?**

it should look like this
[image]

Comment: You need to use ```NSTextAttachment()``` to add button like feature in your text.

Comment: see this for help : ios - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309247/add-read-more-to-the-end-of-uilabel

Comment: @Ashish Unfortunately, I did not find options for adding a button to NSTextAttachment (). Could you give some specifics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on response https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150640/13642906

```
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "awesomeIcon.png")
let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)

fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: nil))
fullString.append(imageString)
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: nil))

self.text.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(showBlurbMessage(tapGesture:)))
self.text.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)
```

in showBlurbMessage

```
 @objc func showBlurbMessage(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = (text.text?.count ?? 0)
    if tapGesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: self.text, inRange: NSRange(location: location - 2, length: 1)) {

        let alert = UIAlertController.createOkAlert(WithTitle: "", message: assessment.blurbDescription, okTitle: "Close")
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and extension for `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

    // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    // Configure textContainer
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0 // 0.0 - left, 0.5 - center, 1 - right
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
    let labelSize = label.bounds.size
    textContainer.size = labelSize

    // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
    let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
    let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
    let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(
        x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
        y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y
    )
    let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(
        x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
        y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y
    )
    let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

    return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSTextAttachment` to add `image` at the end of text.

```
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text")

// Create our NSTextAttachment
let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "awesomeIcon.png")

// Wrap the attachment in its own attributed string so we can append it
let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)

// Add the NSTextAttachment
fullString.append(imageString)

// Draw the result in a label
yourLabel.attributedText = fullString
```

and then add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to trigger action after tap.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(showAlert(tapGesture:)))
yourLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

@objc func showAlert(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    // Show alert
}
```

Comment: good way! But I would like UITapGestureRecognizer to listen only to the image. so trying to add a button

Answer (score 0):

Above solution is working for whole label here is my solution where intercation will happen only on icon not on label

```
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Text ")
        let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "info.png")
        let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
        fullString.append(imageString)
        label.attributedText = fullString
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(infoAction(tapGesture:)))
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

 @objc func infoAction(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: .zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)
        let location = tapGesture.location(in: label)
        let effectiveRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: textStorage.length)
        let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        if NSLocationInRange(characterIndex, effectiveRange), characterIndex == textStorage.length - 1 {
            print("Pressed on image")
        }
    }
```