# Append Button at the end of Multi-Line Text

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a multiline text with info button at the end of the text which is done with HStack at the moment.

```
          HStack(spacing: 15) {
                Image(uiImage: "questionMark")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)

                Text("Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.")
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
          }
```

which looks like this:

[image]

**Goal:**

But I want to have the button at the end of the last text like **infoIcon** should appear right after **ipsum.**

[image]

**Note:**
What could be the best solution to achieve this and would like not to use UIKit in this regards?

Comment: Wrap the `Text` in another `HStack` and set the `alignment: bottom`

Comment: @ClausJørgensen yes that would align the button at the bottom to the text but i want to achieve something like this 

Text + Button

so the button should appear right after the text ending.

Answer (score 3):

The possible solution is to add use Image constructor of Text but you can not add action only the image.
Like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        fullImageText
            .onTapGesture {

            }
    }
    
    var fullImageText: Text {
        Text("Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.") + Text(Image("edit"))
    }
}
```

[image]

Another solution is to use `NSMutableAttributedString` wrap with `UIViewRepresentable`. Here is demo : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62169577/14733292

Comment: It would take align the button at the bottom of the text but i want the button where the text ends.