# Place button right after 1-2 line text ends

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There are pictures of what I want to achieve in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66241376/11627521).

I tried putting the `TextBlock` and the `Button` in a `WrapPanel`, and this works for single-line text but not for multi-line text.

```
<WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock
       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
       TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" .../>
    <Button .../>
</WrapPanel>
```

The picture below shows what's happening. When the `TextBlock` text becomes 2 lines the second line takes the whole width of the first line, which is logical.
[image]

I thought of chopping the string by words and using an `ItemsControl` with `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanel`. But the text may become longer, and there isn't space for more than 2 lines, that's why I put the `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` there; the remaining text will be trimmed and the button will be at the end of the second line, in that case.

Update: Well it turned out to be not so easy, I went with changing my UI to something simpler like putting a rounded button on the right.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind to use `TextBox` insteaf of `TextBlock`, it has [TextBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.getrectfromcharacterindex) method to get the rectangle of character by index number and you can utilize it to adjust the position of `Button` accordingly.

The following is just a proof of concept and there is much room to modify.

Xaml:

```xml
<Grid Width="200" Height="100">
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox"
             TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" AcceptsReturn="True"
             TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    <Button x:Name="button"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Content="END" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    AdjustButtonPosition();
}

private void AdjustButtonPosition()
{
    if (this.textBox is null || this.button is null)
        return;

    var index = textBox.Text.Length;
    var rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(index);

    button.Margin = new Thickness(rect.Right, rect.Top, 0, 0);
    button.Height = rect.Height;
}
```