# How to add "read more" at end of the 3rd line in UILabel in Swift

Tags: swift, text, label, line, action

I need to add `read more` at the end of the 3rd line in label.

**like this i need:**

[image]

**Note:** i have tried this answer [Add "...Read More" to the end of UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309247/add-read-more-to-the-end-of-uilabel) but here read more action is not working and expand collapse also not working.. so tried like below

Actually i need to show description in label.. here if the description if more then 3 lines then i need to show `read more` at end of the 3rd line and need to expand the label with remaining text..

**code:** with this code i can expand the label if more than 3 lines but i need to show `read more` at end of the third line

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 despLbl.text = publicProGenInfo?.result?.user?.description
        despLbl.numberOfLines = 3//despLbl.maxNumberOfLines//3
        let tap:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.labelAction(gesture:)))
        despLbl.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        despLbl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tap.delegate = self

   }

 @objc func labelAction(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
  {
      if despLbl.numberOfLines == 3 {
          despLbl.numberOfLines = despLbl.maxNumberOfLines
      } else {
          despLbl.numberOfLines = 3
      }
  }
```

o/p: getting like this.. here after 3rd line how to add `read more` text... please do guide

[image] [image]

Comment: I would check https://github.com/apploft/ExpandableLabel

Answer (score 0):

[ReadMoreTextView](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView) is a good option for this purpose, with a few lines of code you can achieve this behavior.

```
@IBOutlet weak var aboutMessageTextView: ReadMoreTextView!
aboutMessageTextView.text = "your text"
let readMoreTextAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
     NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.systemBlue,
     NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
   ]
aboutMessageTextView.attributedReadMoreText = NSAttributedString(string: " ... Read more", attributes: readMoreTextAttributes)
aboutMessageTextView.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
aboutMessageTextView.shouldTrim = true
```