# How to add links in label of default UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I am using default `UItableViewCell` to display text. Now lable of that cell is set to multiline as

```
defaultCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

And I have multiple cells containting multiline text. And I want to add links in that text something like below

This is multiLine Text which will lead you to the [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com). And you will find something there.

I searched and found solutions like using `UITextView` instead if `UILable` etc.

But I want to do it with a `UILable`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedtext-of-a-uilabel

Comment: @Randy I do no think its a duplicate because: Most of the answers are in Objective-c and They are SubClassing UiLable. How would you use that with default cell ?

Comment: I would subclass `UITableViewCell` and set a custom `UILabel` as one of its subviews

Comment: Rather subclass `UITableViewCell ` and use `UITextView`, much easier

Comment: I do understand that that I cal create a custom cell and use a lable or UiTextField. But the question How to do that with default cell

Answer (score 2):

You should use `UITextView` and set Detection for Links:

```
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.Link
```

Or if you need labels, then you can use some 3rd party solution like this: https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel
https://github.com/null09264/FRHyperLabel

Comment: Anyone had any luck using `FRHyperLabel` in a `UITableView`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you really want in terms of UX is a link being represented by the entire cell. You should simply implement `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` and send the user to the destination there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I do no want a link being represented by the entire cell. But just the a specific text in the lable of cell.