# How to make accessible links in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a UILabel with text such as the following:

> Please search [Google](http://google.com) for the answer.

I'm aware you can [make links tappable in a UILabel using a UITapGestureRecognizer via a solution like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedtext-of-a-uilabel). The problem is that **if the user is visually impaired and relies on a screen reader, the screen reader doesn't know about the tappable link in the text.**

How can I get a tappable link in a UILabel that is accessible via a screen reader?

Ideally I'm looking for a solution that still works with UILabel rather than a readonly UITextView.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution this this? I have just hit the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simple tap recogniser should help. with simple google search I landed on this [tutorial](http://samwize.com/2016/03/04/how-to-create-multiple-tappable-links-in-a-uilabel/).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of how to do it with a tap gesture recognizer (I'll update the question to clarify that). What I'm looking for is how to make it **accessible** for blind people, for example. In other words, how do I allow a *screen reader* to detect the link?