# iOS:How to get the character at the click position on a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uilabel, textkit

When I click on a  UILabel, I want to get the character of the clicked position, but UILabel has no API，what should I do？

Comment: The trick is, the UILabel has multiple lines, and the text is really attributedText, so it's a bit tough to find the exact character at the click position of the

Comment: The linked answer is originally for UITextView, but explains how to deal with UILabel as well. The key tool is NSLayoutManager.characterIndexForPoint.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240683/how-do-i-detect-and-make-clickable-links-in-a-uilabel-not-using-uitextview/42240972, which includes Swift code and more discussion of the necessary techniques.