# How to show html text in UILabel in iOS- swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to show data coming from server in UICollectionView. the data is coming in html string like given below

```
  <span> recognized <a 

href='#/userProfile/NZ==/XQ=='> Punit Kumar </a> for Delivers on time</span>
```

I want it to be shown like this

[image]

how can I achieve that? Someone please help me.

Comment: You might want to do that with a `UIWebView` since it's not only involving attributed text but also an image.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Image is set at client end. I only want to show that string in UILabel in UICollectionViewCell

Comment: UILabel will not support image.. so use webview instead

Comment: @MoinShirazi the cell contains image view and UILabel, text to be set in UILabel and corresponding image will get set in UIImageView once I get data from server

Comment: Then define what you actually want to do. Don't post things that are basically unrelated. What's your question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Your span contain image first so everyone feels its image so first edit the question properly

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I think, now you can understand the question

Comment: @MoinShirazi I have edited the question.Now you can understand it better.

Answer (score 7):

### Swift 4

Update for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45279219)

```
    extension NSAttributedString {
        internal convenience init?(html: String) {
            guard let data = html.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
                // not sure which is more reliable: String.Encoding.utf16 or String.Encoding.unicode
                return nil
            }
            guard let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) else {
                return nil
            }
            self.init(attributedString: attributedString)
        }
    }

    label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(html: "<span> recognized <a href='#/userProfile/NZ==/XQ=='> Punit Kumar </a> for Delivers on time</span>")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your HTML formatted string into `NSAttributedString`, then set that attributed string as the text of your label.
You can convert your HTML formatted string to `NSAttributedString` using the below extension

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    internal convenience init?(html: String) {
        guard let data = html.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(attributedString: attributedString)
    }
}
```

You can use above extension like this: `let attributedString = NSAttributedString(html: ""<html><body> Some html string </body></html>"")`

Then you can set the attributed string as the text of your `UILabel` using `myLabel.attributedText = attributedString`

Comment: I am using this extension, but I want to it to be shown exactly the same way as it is shown in above attachment. and the underlined text(Punit kumar) must be  clickable

Comment: This copies the full HTML formatting, so it should work. What looks different from the picture when you use this method? Are you sure the link is actually referring to something that is valid in the app as well?

Comment: yeah, the screen shot attached above is actually the screen shot of my android app.

Comment: I just run above code and it displays just as expected. However, to make the link clickable, you will need to do some further work, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedstring-of-a-uilabel). Probably the easiest solution would be to change your `UILabel` to a `UIButton`, which is clickable by default. You can use `button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, for: .normal)` to set the HTML formatted string as the button's title.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
let htmlText = "<html><body> Some html string </body></html>"

guard let data = dicData.desc.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode) else { return }

let attributedText = try! NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType:NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

Swift

```
let htmlText = "<p>etc</p>"

if let htmlData = htmlText.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode) {
    do {
        let attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let e as NSError {
        print("Couldn't translate \(htmlText): \(e.localizedDescription) ")
    }
}
```

Objective-C

```
 NSString * htmlString = @"<html><body> Some html string </body></html>";
NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
myLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

WebView

```
[detailView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='text-align:justify; font-size:13px;font-family:HelveticaNeue;color:#362932;'>%@",[model.dict valueForKey:@"description"]] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Thanx @Allan it worked for me. But now I want to apply css too, is there any way to apply external css to that attributed html string

Comment: @Mansuu.... Just write the style on the html element. like this
<p style='color : red'> this is the red font </p>

Answer (score 0):

> Get html attributed string with font parameter from string

```
extension String
    {
            func getHTMLFromString(htmlText: String,fonthexColor:String,fontName:String,fontSize:Int)->NSAttributedString?
            {
                  let modifiedFont = String(format:"<span style=\"color:\(fonthexColor);font-family:\(fontName); font-size: \(fontSize)\">%@</span>", htmlText)
        
                  let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
                      data: modifiedFont.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                      documentAttributes: nil)
             
                  return attrStr
              }
        }
```