# How can I accurately detect if a link is clicked inside UILabels in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, swift4, nsattributedstring

I have managed to style the links without problem using `NSMutableAttributedString` but I am unable to accurately detect which character has been clicked. I have tried all the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedstring-of-a-uilabel) (that I could convert to Swift 4 code) but with no luck.

The following code works but fails to accurately detect which character has been clicked and gets the wrong location of the link:

```
func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

    // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    // Configure textContainer
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
    let labelSize = label.bounds.size
    textContainer.size = labelSize

    // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
    let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
    let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
    let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)
    let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)
    let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
    print(indexOfCharacter)
    return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel`. I originally, didn't want to use a `UITextView` because I need the element to behave like a `UILabel` and a `UITextView` can cause issues with scrolling and it's intended use, is to be editable text. The following class I wrote makes a `UITextView` behave like a `UILabel` but with fully accurate click detection and no scrolling issues:

```
import UIKit

class ClickableLabelTextView: UITextView {
    var delegate: DelegateForClickEvent?
    var ranges:[(start: Int, end: Int)] = []
    var page: String = ""
    var paragraph: Int?
    var clickedLink: (() -> Void)?
    var pressedTime: Int?
    var startTime: TimeInterval?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        self.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        self.delaysContentTouches = true
        self.isEditable = false
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.isSelectable = false
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let clickedLink = clickedLink {
            if let startTime = startTime {
                self.startTime = nil
                if (Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime <= 0.2) {
                    clickedLink()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        var location = point
        location.x -= self.textContainerInset.left
        location.y -= self.textContainerInset.top
        if location.x > 0 && location.y > 0 {
            let index = self.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: self.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
            var count = 0
            for range in ranges {
                if index >= range.start && index < range.end {
                    clickedLink = {
                        self.delegate?.clickedLink(page: self.page, paragraph: self.paragraph, linkNo: count)
                    }
                    return self
                }
                count += 1
            }
        }
        clickedLink = nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

The function `hitTest` get's called multiple times but that never causes a problem, as `clickedLink()` will only ever get called once per click. I tried disabling `isUserInteractionEnabled` for different views but didn't that didn't help and was unnecessary.

To use the class, simply add it to your `UITextView`. If you're using `autoLayout` in the Xcode editor, then disable `Scrolling Enabled` for the `UITextView` in the editor to avoid layout warnings.

In the `Swift` file that contains the code to go with your `xib` file (in my case a class for a `UITableViewCell`, you need to set the following variables for your clickable textView:

- `ranges` - the start and end index of every clickable link with the `UITextView`
- `page` - a `String` to identify the page or view that contains the the `UITextView`
- `paragraph` - If you have multiple clickable `UITextView`, assign each one with an number
- `delegate` - to delegate the click events to where ever you are able to process them.

You then need to create a protocol for your `delegate`:

```
protocol DelegateName {
    func clickedLink(page: String, paragraph: Int?, linkNo: Int?)
}
```

The variables passed into `clickedLink` give you all the information you need to know which link has been clicked.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't mind rewriting you code, you should use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`.

You can easily detect the link by setting `UITextView`'s `dataDetectorTypes`and implement the delegate function to retrieve your clicked urls.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, 
    in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool
```

### Example

As it's hard to maintain and/or update two posts, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65980444/8740349

> See also official docs:
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1649337-textview

Comment: I was considering using a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel` but a colleague advised against it because it could cause issues, as I am placing the labels inside a cell of a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`.

Comment: Your team might have reasons that I may not know then. Although I think this is the easiest way to achieve the result.

Comment: It's just me that's making the app, however, I've only started learning IOS development less than 1 month ago. When I am back at work, I will have a go with `UITextView` and find out what problems it causes, if any, unless of course I am able to fix it with `UILabel`.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to avoid posting an answer since it's more a comment on Dan Bray's own answer (can't comment due to lack of rep). However, I still think it's worth sharing.

---

I made some small (what I think are) improvements to Dan Bray's answer for convenience:

- I found it a bit awkward to setup the textView with the ranges and
  stuff so I replaced that part with a `textLink` dict which stores the
  link strings and their respective targets. The implementing viewController only needs to set this to initialize the textView.
- I added the underline style to the links (keeping the font etc. from interface builder). Feel free to add your own styles here (like blue font color etc.).
- I reworked the callback's signature to make it more easy to be processed.
- Note that I also had to rename the `delegate` to `linkDelegate` since UITextViews do have a delegate already.

The TextView:

```
import UIKit

class LinkTextView: UITextView {
  private var callback: (() -> Void)?
  private var pressedTime: Int?
  private var startTime: TimeInterval?
  private var initialized = false
  var linkDelegate: LinkTextViewDelegate?
  var textLinks: [String : String] = Dictionary() {
    didSet {
        initialized = false
        styleTextLinks()
    }
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    self.delaysContentTouches = true
    self.isEditable = false
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.isSelectable = false
    styleTextLinks()
  }

  private func styleTextLinks() {
    guard !initialized && !textLinks.isEmpty else {
        return
    }
    initialized = true

    let alignmentStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    alignmentStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment        

    let input = self.text ?? ""
    let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : self.textColor!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font : self.font!,
        .paragraphStyle : alignmentStyle
    ]
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: input, attributes: attributes)

    for textLink in textLinks {
        let range = (input as NSString).range(of: textLink.0)
        if range.lowerBound != NSNotFound {
            attributedString.addAttribute(.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: range)
        }
    }

    attributedText = attributedString
  }

  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    startTime = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
  }

  override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let callback = callback {
        if let startTime = startTime {
            self.startTime = nil
            if (Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - startTime <= 0.2) {
                callback()
            }
        }
    }
  }

  override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    var location = point
    location.x -= self.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= self.textContainerInset.top
    if location.x > 0 && location.y > 0 {
        let index = self.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: self.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        for textLink in textLinks {
            let range = ((text ?? "") as NSString).range(of: textLink.0)
            if NSLocationInRange(index, range) {
                callback = {
                    self.linkDelegate?.didTap(text: textLink.0, withLink: textLink.1, inTextView: self)
                }
                return self
            }
        }
    }
    callback = nil
    return nil
  }
}
```

The delegate:

```
import Foundation

protocol LinkTextViewDelegate {
  func didTap(text: String, withLink link: String, inTextView textView: LinkTextView)
}
```

The implementing viewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  myLinkTextView.linkDelegate = self
  myLinkTextView.textLinks = [
    "click here" : "https://wwww.google.com",
    "or here" : "#myOwnAppHook"
  ]
}
```

And last but not least a big thank you to Dan Bray, who's solution this is after all!

Comment: Using a `Dictionary` is a slight improvement, as it avoids the risk of multiple instances of the same range being created. As for styling with `NSMutableAttributedString`, I already do that but I chose to keep the code out of the class and use it just for detecting the links because not every link will necessarily be styled the same way.

Comment: Great solution. Just a word of warning, if the UITextView isn't contained within a UIView, then you risk triggering the delegate callback whenever you click somewhere on the enclosing superview at a location wherever the x and y are greater than the origin of the text view.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MLLabel library. MLLabel is a subclass of UIlabel. The library has a class MLLinkLabel that is subclass of MLLabel. That means you can use it in place of UIlabel (even in interface builder just drag a UILabel and change it's class to MLLinkLabel)

MLLinkLabel can do the trick for you and it is very easy. Here is an example:

```
    label.didClickLinkBlock = {(link, linkText, label) -> Void in

        //Here you can check the type of the link and do whatever you want.
        switch link!.linkType {
        case .email:
            break
        case .none:
             break
        case .URL:
             break
        case .phoneNumber:
             break
        case .userHandle:
             break
        case .hashtag:
             break
        case .other:
             break
        }

    }
```

you can check the library in GitHub https://github.com/molon/MLLabel

Here is a screenshot from one of my apps that I used MLLabel in it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need a subclass of `Label`, solution may be something like one prepared in a playground (of cause some points should be optimized because this is just a draft):

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension String {
    // MARK: - String+RangeDetection

    func rangesOfPattern(patternString: String) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var ranges : [Range<Index>] = []

        let patternCharactersCount = patternString.count
        let strCharactersCount = self.count
        if  strCharactersCount >= patternCharactersCount {

            for i in 0...(strCharactersCount - patternCharactersCount) {
                let from:Index = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy:i)
                if let to:Index = self.index(from, offsetBy:patternCharactersCount, limitedBy: self.endIndex) {

                    if patternString == self[from..<to] {
                        ranges.append(from..<to)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return ranges
    }

    func nsRange(from range: Range<String.Index>) -> NSRange? {
        let utf16view = self.utf16
        if let from = range.lowerBound.samePosition(in: utf16view),
            let to = range.upperBound.samePosition(in: utf16view) {
            return NSMakeRange(utf16view.distance(from: utf16view.startIndex, to: from),
                               utf16view.distance(from: from, to: to))
        }
        return nil
    }

    func range(from nsRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>? {
        guard
            let from16 = utf16.index(utf16.startIndex, offsetBy: nsRange.location, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let to16 = utf16.index(from16, offsetBy: nsRange.length, limitedBy: utf16.endIndex),
            let from = String.Index(from16, within: self),
            let to = String.Index(to16, within: self)
            else { return nil }
        return from ..< to
    }
}

final class TappableLabel: UILabel {

    private struct Const {
        static let DetectableAttributeName = "DetectableAttributeName"
    }

    var detectableText: String?
    var displayableContentText: String?

    var mainTextAttributes:[NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject] = [:]
    var tappableTextAttributes:[NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject] = [:]

    var didDetectTapOnText:((_:String, NSRange) -> ())?

    private var tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer?

    // MARK: - Public

    func performPreparation() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.prepareDetection()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func prepareDetection() {

        guard let searchableString = self.displayableContentText else { return }
        let attributtedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: searchableString, attributes: mainTextAttributes)

        if let detectionText = detectableText {

            var attributesForDetection:[NSAttributedStringKey : AnyObject] = [
                NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: Const.DetectableAttributeName) : "UserAction" as AnyObject
            ]
            tappableTextAttributes.forEach {
                attributesForDetection.updateValue($1, forKey: $0)
            }

            for (_ ,range) in searchableString.rangesOfPattern(patternString: detectionText).enumerated() {
                let tappableRange = searchableString.nsRange(from: range)
                attributtedString.addAttributes(attributesForDetection, range: tappableRange!)
            }

            if self.tapGesture == nil {
                setupTouch()
            }
        }

        text = nil
        attributedText = attributtedString
    }

    private func setupTouch() {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TappableLabel.detectTouch(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        self.tapGesture = tapGesture
    }

    @objc private func detectTouch(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let attributedText = attributedText, gesture.state == .ended else {
            return
        }

        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: bounds.size)
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = numberOfLines

        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)

        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: attributedText)
        textStorage.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: font, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        let locationOfTouchInLabel = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)

        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)
        var alignmentOffset: CGFloat!
        switch textAlignment {
        case .left, .natural, .justified:
            alignmentOffset = 0.0
        case .center:
            alignmentOffset = 0.5
        case .right:
            alignmentOffset = 1.0
        }
        let xOffset = ((bounds.size.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * alignmentOffset) - textBoundingBox.origin.x
        let yOffset = ((bounds.size.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * alignmentOffset) - textBoundingBox.origin.y
        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - xOffset, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - yOffset)

        let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        if characterIndex < textStorage.length {
            let tapRange = NSRange(location: characterIndex, length: 1)
            let substring = (self.attributedText?.string as? NSString)?.substring(with: tapRange)

            let attributeName = Const.DetectableAttributeName
            let attributeValue = self.attributedText?.attribute(NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: attributeName), at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? String
            if let _ = attributeValue,
                let substring = substring {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.didDetectTapOnText?(substring, tapRange)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}


class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = TappableLabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.displayableContentText = "Hello World! stackoverflow"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        label.detectableText = "World!"
        label.didDetectTapOnText = { (value1, value2) in
            print("\(value1) - \(value2)\n")
        }
        label.performPreparation()

        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Dan Bray's solution above to work for me I had to call `super.hitTest(point, with:event)` instead of returning `nil`. Otherwise `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` were not invoked. I use the textViews inside a `UIScrollView`.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    var location = point
    location.x -= self.textContainerInset.left
    location.y -= self.textContainerInset.top
    if location.x > 0 && location.y > 0 {


    let index = self.layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: self.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)
        for textLink in textLinks {
            let range = ((text ?? "") as NSString).range(of: textLink.0)
            if NSLocationInRange(index, range) {
                callback = {
                    self.linkDelegate?.didTap(text: textLink.0, withLink: textLink.1, inTextView: self)
                }
                return self
            }
        }
    }
    callback = nil
    return super.hitTest(point, with:event)
}
```