# Add a hyperlink to UIlabel

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I am learning mobile app development and I am trying to add a link to a label, and would like some guidance and this is the code for the label

```
     var LinkLabel = new UILabel()
        {
            Frame = new CGRect(20, 170, View.Bounds.Width - 40, 40),
            TextColor = UIColor.Blue,
            TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
            Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(24),
            Text = "Label",
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need code in Xamarin.iOS:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var LinkLabel = new UILabel()
    {
        Frame = new CGRect(20, 170, View.Bounds.Width - 40, 40),
        TextColor = UIColor.Blue,
        TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
        Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(24),
        Text = "Label",
        UserInteractionEnabled = true
    };

    Add(LinkLabel);

    Action action = () => {

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("https://www.google.com"));

    };

    UITapGestureRecognizer tapGes = new UITapGestureRecognizer(action);
    LinkLabel.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGes);
}
```

You can easily add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label and handle the event when user click it. Remember to set label's `UserInteractionEnabled` to true.

If you want the whole text is clickable, you can use [a button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/buttons) instead.

If you want part of the text is clickable, you should use `NSMutableAttributedString`, you can check the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedstring-of-a-uilabel), I can help you to translate the solutions to C# if you need.

Answer (score -1):

with this code, you can add action to your label

```
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourAction(sender:)))
 LinkLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

 @objc func yourAction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: messageStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "link", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

in the handler says nil because when your click the alert controller, the action will be close the view