# How to open a view controller on click of hyperlink on UILabel in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have to open a view controller via a hyperlink on a `UILabel`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedstring-of-a-uilabel) only worked halfway for me. I cannot use `UITextView` according to my project requirement.

The following code creates a hyperlink on a `UILabel` and detects touch on the link but I want to open a view controller instead of an URL.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) @IBOutlet UILabel *label;
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager;
NSTextContainer *textContainer;
NSTextStorage *textStorage;
```

Create hyperlink on a `UILabel`:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"String with a link" attributes:nil];
NSRange linkRange = NSMakeRange(14, 4);
NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.05 green:0.4 blue:0.65 alpha:1.0],
                                  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) };
[attributedString setAttributes:linkAttributes range:linkRange];
_label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

// To detect touches on this Hyperlink.

```
_label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[_label addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapOnLabel:)]];
```

**To Find out tap was on link, not on any other portion of the label.**

// Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage

```
layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeZero];
textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];
```

// Configure layoutManager, textStorage and textContainer

```
[layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

[textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
textContainer.lineBreakMode = _label.lineBreakMode;
textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines =_label.numberOfLines;
```

// each time the label changes its frame, update textContainer's size:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    textContainer.size = self.label.bounds.size;
}
```

// detect whether the tap was exactly on the link:

```
- (void)handleTapOnLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
{
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInLabel = [tapGesture locationInView:tapGesture.view];
    CGSize labelSize = tapGesture.view.bounds.size;
    CGRect textBoundingBox = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
    CGPoint textContainerOffset = CGPointMake((labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x,
                                              (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y);
    CGPoint locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPointMake(locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x,
                                                         locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y);
    NSInteger indexOfCharacter = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:locationOfTouchInTextContainer
                                                       inTextContainer:textContainer
                              fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:nil];
    NSRange linkRange = NSMakeRange(14, 4);
    if (NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, linkRange)) {
        // Open an URL, or handle the tap on the link in any other way
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stackoverflow.com/"]];
    }
}
```

// using this function to present newViewController

```
-(void)navigateToTATViewController{
    TATViewController *tatVC = [[self getStoryboardWithStoryboardType: kListingStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"TATViewControllerID"];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController: tatVC animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: First, is this code working for you, to the point where you are identifying where the tap is? You state in your question: *"I have to open ViewController"* ... what do you mean by **"open"**? Are you in a navigation stack and you're asking how to `push` to a new controller? Are you asking how to `present` a new controller?

Comment: Yes This code is working for me and I can identify where the tap is. I am asking how to present a new controller?

Comment: I guess that `navigateToTATViewController` is called, but `tatVC` not showing? Do you have a `UINavigationController`, ie is `self.navigationController` not nil? What's wrong currently with that line? Why don't use `[self presentViewController:...]` instead?

Comment: Thanks @Larme..my code is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you need to update the line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stackoverflow.com/"]];
```

and replace it with `[self navigateToTATViewController]`;